# Add Time column by adding timedelata in pandas

Tags: pandas

i have a pandas dataframe df:

```
id    value     mins
1      a         12.4
2      u         14.2
3      i         16.2
3      g         17.0
```

i have a datetime.datetime variable:

```
current_time = datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 2, 14, 0, 34, 628481)
```

i want to add new column in my df `'total_time'`
such that for every row it add the delta value mins in current_time.

```
id    value     mins        total_time
1      a         12.4   current_time+timedelta(minutes = 12.4)
2      u         14.2            and
3      i         16.2            so
3      g         17.0            on... for every row
```

i tried:

```
df['total_time' = current_time+timedelta(minutes = df['mins'].item())
```

but i got an error:

`can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar`

Is there any other way of doing this?

i'm using datetime.datetime package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) with `T` for minutes:

```
df['total_time'] = current_time + pd.to_timedelta(df['mins'], unit='T')
print (df)
   id value  mins                 total_time
0   1     a  12.4 2018-01-02 14:12:58.628481
1   2     u  14.2 2018-01-02 14:14:46.628481
2   3     i  16.2 2018-01-02 14:16:46.628481
3   3     g  17.0 2018-01-02 14:17:34.628481
```

Detail:

```
print (pd.to_timedelta(df['mins'], unit='T'))
0   00:12:24
1   00:14:12
2   00:16:12
3   00:17:00
Name: mins, dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Comment: Wow! nice! also if i had to add one more column as `timestamp`, can i do it by this - `    df['timestamp'] = int(datetime.timestamp(df['total_time']))
` ?

Comment: I tried using this:
`    df['timestamp'] = int(datetime.timestamp(pd.to_datetime(df['total_time']))) ` but got error:
`descriptor 'timestamp' requires a 'datetime.datetime' object but received a 'Series'`

Comment: Not sure if understand, what is new column? It is datetimes? Can you explain more? Or need something like `20180102141258628481` ?

Comment: Do you need create integers from datetimes?

Comment: ok leave that, i see an issue : the datatype of my `current_time = datetime.datetime`, but type of the total_time in my` df = pandas.tslib.Timestamp` Can't i maintain same datatype as datetime.datetime?

Comment: current_time+timedelta(minutes = float_value) returns datetime.datetime object only

Comment: It is not so easy, because in pandas by default are timestamp. By I try find some solution.

Comment: its okay, its that's tough, i'll try to even work with this :)

Comment: There is posible use `df['total_time'].dt.to_pydatetime()` from [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22825954/2901002), but if assign to new column there are datetimes again.

Comment: this to_pydatetime() is also very helpful!