# Iterate through defined Datetime index range in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops, datetime

I can see from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50309609/iterating-over-a-list-of-dates-from-datetime-index) how to iterate through a list of dates from a datetime index. However, I would like to define the range of dates using:

```
my_df['Some_Column'].first_valid_index()
```

and

```
my_df['Some_Column'].last_valid_index()
```

My attempt looks like this:

```
for today_index, values  in range(my_df['Some_Column'].first_valid_index() ,my_df['Some_Column'].last_valid_index()):
    print(today_index)
```

However I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Timestamp' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

How do I inform the loop to restrict to those specific dates?

Comment: Answer was edited, `date_range` return DatetimeIndex, so need `for val in r:`, in your `update` use `today_index` instaed `today_index, values`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`date_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
s = my_df['Some_Column'].first_valid_index()
e = my_df['Some_Column'].last_valid_index()

r = pd.date_range(s, e)
```

And for loop use:

```
for val in r:
    print (val)
```

If need selecting rows in `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.loc[s:e]
```