# Transforming dates: from year and week number into datetime

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, week-number

I am trying to transform the following dataframe

```
id  year  week 
 1  2018    43
 1  2019     1
 2  2019     4
 3  2018    51
```

into a dataframe containing the following column

```
id  year  week  year_week
 1  2018    43    2018-43
 1  2019     1     2019-1
 2  2019     4     2019-4
 3  2018    51    2018-51
```

where "year_week" is a datetime type

Comment: What kind of datetime is `2018-43`?

Comment: To build a date you need year, month and day, with year_week you can know month but not day

Comment: @Blorgbeard `datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%W')` -> `2019-11`

Answer (score 5):

You will need to pick a day of the week in order to create your timestamp from that data. Assuming these are [ISO weeks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), I picked "1" for the Monday that begins the ISO week (also added a column to convert to the string format shown in your question).

If you really want the column data to be [datetime objects](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) instead of [pandas.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), see [Converting between datetime and Timestamp objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22825349/converting-between-datetime-and-pandas-timestamp-objects) for another step you will need to include.

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def year_week(y, w):
    return datetime.strptime(f'{y} {w} 1', '%G %V %u')

df = pd.DataFrame([(2018, 43), (2019, 1), (2019, 4), (2018, 51)], columns=['year', 'week'])
df['year_week_ts'] = df.apply(lambda row: year_week(row.year, row.week), axis=1)
df['year_week_str'] = df.apply(lambda row: row.year_week_ts.strftime('%G-%V'), axis=1)

print(df)
#    year  week year_week_ts year_week_str
# 0  2018    43   2018-10-22       2018-43
# 1  2019     1   2018-12-31       2019-01
# 2  2019     4   2019-01-21       2019-04
# 3  2018    51   2018-12-17       2018-51

# for python 3 versions pre-3.6 use '{} {} 1'.format(y, w) instead of the f string above
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look over the [epiweeks](https://pypi.org/project/epiweeks/) package!

Given the data you provided and assuming the ISO week numbering system, let's say that you want to create a column with the week ending date:

```py
from epiweeks import Week

df['ending'] = df.apply(
        lambda row: pd.to_datetime(Week(row.year, row.week, 'iso').enddate()),
        axis=1
)
```

That results in a new column of datetime type.

Hopefully that what you are looking for.