# Pandas Convert Series from DateTimeStamp to datetime.datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas' dataframe with a column that is of datatype: `datetime64[ns]`.

How do I convert the whole series to a Python's Datetime.datetime objects?  On the individual object there is a function called `to_datetime()`, but I can't call this function on the series.

Thank you

Comment: It is really problematic, because it automatically cast to pandas datetimes, but is possible convert to `numpy array` of dates by `df.Date.dt.to_pydatetime()`

Comment: So this `df.Date = df.Date.dt.to_pydatetime()` still return `Date    datetime64[ns]`

Comment: better it is explain [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23191196/2901002)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If performance is a concern I would advise to use the following function to convert those columns to `date_time`:

```
def lookup(s):
    """
    This is an extremely fast approach to datetime parsing.
    For large data, the same dates are often repeated. Rather than
    re-parse these, we store all unique dates, parse them, and
    use a lookup to convert all dates.
    """
    dates = {date:pd.to_datetime(date) for date in s.unique()}
    return s.apply(lambda v: dates[v])
```

> ```
> to_datetime: 5799 ms
> dateutil:    5162 ms
> strptime:    1651 ms
> manual:       242 ms
> lookup:        32 ms
> ```

Comment: @erip great solution!  Works very well.

Comment: @codebase5000 It's not my solution! It's SerialDev's.