# Converting datetime string to datetime in numpy (python)

Tags: datetime, python-3.x, numpy, pandas, python-datetime

I would like to convert

```
['17-10-2010 07:15:30', '13-05-2011 08:20:35', "15-01-2013 09:09:09"]
```

into a `Numpy` datetime object.

```
import numpy as np
[np.datetime64(x) for x in ['17-10-2010 07:15:30', '13-05-2011 08:20:35', "15-01-2013 09:09:09"]]
```

raised `ValueError: Could not convert object to NumPy datetime`. However, the following works as I intended

```
[np.datetime64(x) for x in ['2010-10-17 07:15:30', '2011-05-13 08:20:35', "2012-01-15 09:09:09"]]
```

How can I convert my array into a format that conforms with `Numpy`'s `datetime64` function requirement?

I am using Numpy version 1.7.0. in python 3.4

Answer (score 22, accepted):

So far as I can tell, `np.datetime64` only works with

> [strings in ISO 8601 date or datetime format](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html)

The `to_datetime` function in `pandas` seems to be more flexible:

```
import pandas as pd
a=pd.to_datetime(['17-10-2010 07:15:30', '13-05-2011 08:20:35', "15-01-2013 09:09:09"])
```

Of course you can easily convert back to `numpy`:

```
np.array(a,dtype=np.datetime64)
```

Comment: np.array(a,dtype=np.datetime64) is great but it returns '17-10-2010T07:15:30', how to make it '17-10-2010 07:15:30' ?

Comment: "*The to_datetime function in pandas seems to be more flexible*", but in that case, be aware of the [date/time nightmare in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921593/774575)

Answer (score 2):

`np.datetime64` works with format `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

If you have a list of 5-6 elements you can directly make use of `np.datetime64` data type by just changing the `format(yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)` of date in your `list`

for example:

```
dates=['17-10-2010 07:15:30', '13-05-2011 08:20:35', "15-01-2013 09:09:09"]
#to
dates=['2010-10-17 07:15:30', '2011-05-13 08:20:35', "2013-01-15 09:09:09"]
#then create an array by
np.array(dates,dtype=np.datetime64)
```

**Note:** Having 5-6 elements inside `list` is not an ideal case(when comes to real data) so you have to use [`to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method in `pandas` as it is more flexible and efficient:

**In addition to answer given by** [`@atomh33ls`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1461850/atomh33ls):

After using `to_datetime()` method in `pandas`
you can easily convert that back to `numpy` by using `values` attribute or `to_numpy()` method

```
a.values
#OR
a.to_numpy()
```