# Passing chopped down datetimes

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have been stumped for the past few hours trying to solve the following.

In a large data set I have from an automated system, there is a DATE_TIME value, which for rows at midnight has values that dont have a the full hour like: *12-MAY-2017  0:16:20*

When I try convert this to a date (so that its usable for conversions) as follows:

```
df['DATE_TIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

I get the following error:

```
Error parsing datetime string "12-MAY-2017  0:16:20" at position 3
```

I tried writing some REGEX to pull out each piece but couldnt get anything working given the hour could be either 1 or two characters respectively. It also doesn't seem like an ideal solution to write regex for each peice.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use [pandas.to_datetime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) method:

```
df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'], errors='coerce')
```

Parameter `errors='coerce'` will take care of those strings that can't be converted to `datatime` dtype

Answer (score 3):

I think you need [`pandas.to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) only:

```
df  = pd.DataFrame({'DATE_TIME':['12-MAY-2017 0:16:20','12-MAY-2017 0:16:20']})
print (df)
             DATE_TIME
0  12-MAY-2017 0:16:20
1  12-MAY-2017 0:16:20

df['DATE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE_TIME'])
print (df)
            DATE_TIME
0 2017-05-12 00:16:20
1 2017-05-12 00:16:20
```

Convert in numpy by `astype` seems [problematic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27103854/2901002), because need `strings in ISO 8601 date or datetime format`:

```
df['DATE_TIME'].astype('datetime64[ns]')
```

> ValueError: Error parsing datetime string "12-MAY-2017 0:16:20" at position 3

EDIT:

If datetimes are broken (some strings or ints) then use [MaxU  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45587709/2901002).