# How to convert numpy array from numpy.int64 to datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, datetime

I have the following array of type `<class 'numpy.ndarray'>`

```
array([20181010, 20181031, 20181116, 20181012, 20181005, 20181008,
       20181130, 20181011, 20181005, 20181116])
```

How can I convert its constituents from the current type `<class 'numpy.int64'>` to datetime in `numpy`? I want to find a quick way and my understanding is that using a loop or list comprehension, as well as converting this `numpy.array` to `pandas` or to a `list` will be slower.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

P.S. This question may have been answered somewhere, but I could not find a single solution which works.

Comment: @Nixon, The answers there, though.. aren't ideal. Surely there's a better target?

Comment: I think `@Sebastian's answer is superior to the duplicate, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103044/converting-datetime-string-to-datetime-in-numpy-python, even though both use `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried the duplicate and I tried Sebastian's answer, and indeed I share your view as well. Hence the reason why I upvoted and marked as correct (and why I could not get a full answer from what was marked as duplicate when asking the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` has a better concept of what can be considered a date:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
arr = np.array([20181010, 20181031, 20181116, 20181012, 20181005, 
                20181008, 20181130, 20181011, 20181005, 20181116])
pd.to_datetime(arr.astype(str)).values
```

Running this over a set of 10,000,000 entries:

```
%%prun import numpy as np; import pandas as pd
lst = [20181010, 20181031, 20181116, 20181012, 20181005, 
       20181008, 20181130, 20181011, 20181005, 20181116]*1000000
arr = np.array(lst)
arr_str = arr.astype(str)
pd.to_datetime(arr_str).values
```

produces a `prun` of

```
   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    8.977    8.977    8.977    8.977 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
        1    4.394    4.394    4.394    4.394 {built-in method pandas._libs.tslib.array_to_datetime}
        2    2.344    1.172    2.344    1.172 {built-in method pandas._libs.algos.ensure_object}
        4    0.918    0.229    0.918    0.229 {built-in method numpy.core.multiarray.array}
        1    0.313    0.313    7.053    7.053 datetimes.py:106(to_datetime)
...
```

It's efficient enough.

Comment: In terms of time, how does the conversion to pandas play out? Also, I want to have `np.array` as a final result. Will this be costly?

Comment: No, pandas is also vectorized like numpy; see my edit.

Comment: `pandas` does a lot of stuff with Python iterations.  `vectorized` is a slippery term.  To get speed the underlying code needs to be compiled, without a lot of repetative calls to Python classes and objects.

Comment: In the `prun` I don't see any function which is called 10,000,000 times as one would expect by creating 10,000,000 datetime objects. This leads me to believe that pandas does through some level of compilation.

Comment: This actually produces `np.datetime[ns]` dtype array.  That may be what you want.  But if you actually want `datetime.date` objects you'll need an added step: `.astype('datetime64[D]').tolist()`