# Convert numpy array of strings to datetime

Tags: python, numpy, date, datetime, type-conversion

I am shocked at how long I've been running around down various rabbit holes trying to figure this problem out which (I thought) should be relatively simple.

I have a numpy array of strings saved as variable `t` with some associated data as raw_data:

```
t = array(['20141017000000','20141017000001','20141017000002'],dtype='<U14')
raw_data = np.array([1,2,3],dtype='float')
```

The date format is YYYYmmddHHMMSS

I just want to convert this to a datetime object that is compatible with matplotlib for plotting purposes.

Various answers I've found inevitably lead to errors including:

Option #1

```
import matplotlib.dates as dates
convertedDate = dates.num2date(t)

Error: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Option #2 ([from here](https://datagy.io/python-string-to-date/))

```
from datetime import datetime
convertedDate = datetime.strptime(t, '%YY%mm%dd%HH%MM%ss')
Error: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not numpy.ndarray
```

Option #3 (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103044/converting-datetime-string-to-datetime-in-numpy-python))

```
import numpy as np
convertedDate = [np.datetime64(x) for x in t]
```

While this option 3 works, the output doesn't quite make sense to me since it looks identical to the original string for example `convertedDate[0]` returns `numpy.datetime64('20141017000000')`. And furthermore when I try to plot it I get this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(convertedDate,raw_data)
OverflowError: int too big to convert
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pandas`:

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd

dti = pd.to_datetime(t, format='%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
```

Output:

```
>>> dti
DatetimeIndex(['2014-10-17 00:00:00', '2014-10-17 00:00:01',
               '2014-10-17 00:00:02'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)

>>> dti.values
array(['2014-10-17T00:00:00.000000000', '2014-10-17T00:00:01.000000000',
       '2014-10-17T00:00:02.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can use this method
`datetime.strptime(date_string, format)`

Comment: You can improve your answer by providing an example of your solution for others to use. [How do I write a good answer to a question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656)