# timedelta64 and datetime conversion

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I have two datetime (Timestamp) formatted columns in my dataframe, `df['start'], df['end']`. I'd like to get the duration between the two dates. So I create the duration column

```
df['duration'] = df['start'] - df['end']
```

However, now the `duration` column is formatted as `numpy.timedelta64`, instead of `datetime.timedelta` as I would expect.

```
>>> df['duration'][0]
>>> numpy.timedelta64(0,'ns')
```

While

```
>>> df['start'][0] - df['end'][0]
>>> datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Can someone explain to me why the array subtraction change the `timedelta` type? Is there a way that I keep the `datetime.timedelta` as it is easier to work with?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64)

Comment: Whilst that question will no doubt be useful, it's **not** a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was one of the motivations for implementing a Timedelta scalar in pandas 0.15.0. See full docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html)

In >= 0.15.0 the implementation of a `timedelta64[ns]` Series is still `np.timedelta64[ns]` under the hood, but all is completely hidden from the user in a `datetime.timedelta` sub-classed scalar, `Timedelta` (which is basically a useful superset of timedelta and the numpy version).

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame([[pd.Timestamp('20130102'),
                         pd.Timestamp('20130101')]],
                        columns=list('AB'))

In [2]: df['diff'] = df['A'] - df['B']

In [3]: df.dtypes
Out[3]: 
A        datetime64[ns]
B        datetime64[ns]
diff    timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object

# this will return a Timedelta in 0.15.2
In [4]: df['A'][0] - df['B'][0]
Out[4]: datetime.timedelta(1)

In [5]: (df['A'] - df['B'])[0] 
Out[5]: Timedelta('1 days 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Thanks! That's very helpful. Just a question, how can I upgrade the pandas module then?