# How to convert numpy datetime64 into datetime

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I basically face the same problem posted here:[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64)

but I couldn't find satisfying answer from it, my question how to extract datetime from numpy.datetime64 type:

if I try:

```
np.datetime64('2012-06-18T02:00:05.453000000-0400').astype(datetime.datetime)
```

it gave me:
     1339999205453000000L

my current solution is convert datetime64 into a string and then turn to datetime again. but it seems quite a silly method.

Comment: That `L` value is the same you get from `.tolist()`

Comment: I found from the `test` file, that dtype 'M8[ms]' readily converts to `datetime`.

Comment: have your read [my answer *to the end*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13704307/4279)? Have you noticed that different numpy versions behave differently here? The answer contains code for different `numpy` versions (the versions are *explicitly* specified). There is even code example that produces `long` number and then later is shown how to get `datetime` in this case.

Comment: I'm sorry but both the original answer and this one are confusing. There seem to be a lot of different ways of doing it and I'm still not any clearer on the question of how to convert a numpy datetime to a pandas date time. For example, I am not clear if the solution below is saying that: `pdDateTime = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.tolist()/1e9)`   ??

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Borrowing from
[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64)

```
In [220]: x
Out[220]: numpy.datetime64('2012-06-17T23:00:05.453000000-0700')

In [221]: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x.tolist()/1e9)
Out[221]: datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 18, 6, 0, 5, 452999)
```

Accounting for timezones I think that's right.  Looks rather clunky though.

Using `int()` is *more explicit* (I think) than `tolist())`:

```
In [294]: datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(x)/1e9)
Out[294]: datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 18, 6, 0, 5, 452999)
```

or to get datetime in local:

```
In [295]: datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(x.astype('O')/1e9)
```

But in the `test_datetime.py` file
https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/tests/test_datetime.py

I find some other options - first convert the general `datetime64` to one of the format that specifies units:

```
In [296]: x.astype('M8[D]').astype('O')
Out[296]: datetime.date(2012, 6, 18)

In [297]: x.astype('M8[ms]').astype('O')
Out[297]: datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 18, 6, 0, 5, 453000)
```

This works for arrays:

```
In [303]: np.array([[x,x],[x,x]],dtype='M8[ms]').astype('O')[0,1]
Out[303]: datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 18, 6, 0, 5, 453000)
```

Comment: See [my comment to @eumiro's answer (that you've borrowed from)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64#comment18832246_13703930).

Comment: So the `long` is the result of the units being `[ns]`

Comment: Thanks for this. Its amazing.

Comment: At first glance I thought that `x.tolist()/1e9` was a mistake, because I didn't notice that `x` was a scalar in your case. I strongly suggest replacing it with `x.item()` to clarify.

Answer (score 22):

Note that Timestamp IS a sub-class of datetime.datetime so the [4] will generally work

```
In [4]: pd.Timestamp(np.datetime64('2012-06-18T02:00:05.453000000-0400'))
Out[4]: Timestamp('2012-06-18 06:00:05.453000')

In [5]: pd.Timestamp(np.datetime64('2012-06-18T02:00:05.453000000-0400')).to_pydatetime()
Out[5]: datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 18, 6, 0, 5, 453000)
```

Comment: See [@Wes McKinney's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13753918/4279)

Comment: the bug Wes described was fixed quite a while ago

Comment: I meant that you've used the answer without attribution

Comment: oh I didn't realize he had one for this exact topic - so noted

Comment: ["This exact topic"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13703720/4279) is linked in the question. [At the very least you should have read existing answers in the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290816/4279) before answering.

Comment: a perfect answer

Comment: Awesome answer, Jeff! Much simpler to convert datetime64 to datetime

Comment: This approach is deprecated  `DeprecationWarning: parsing timezone aware datetimes is deprecated; this will raise an error in the future`