# How to use Pandas groupby method to bin hours with the 00:00 hour as the center of first bin

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-xarray

Using the Pandas `groupby` method to group data by hour of day is straightforward:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create a sample dataset, a value for each hour in 48 hour
size = 48
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(size), 
                  index=pd.date_range('2021-01-01', periods=size, freq='H'))

# Group the data by hour of day and find the mean
df.groupby(df.index.hour).mean()
```

Sometimes, it is needed to group the hours into bins, and this is accomplished with the `pandas.cut` method as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64015335/2383070).
This bins the hours into `00:00-05:59`, `06:00-11:59`, `12:00-17:59`, and `18:00-23:59`

```py
# Group by bins
bins = [0, 6, 12, 18, 24]
df['time_bin'] = pd.cut(df.index.hour, bins, right=False)
df.groupby('time_bin').mean()
```

However, binning the hours so that the hour 00:00 is in the *center* of the first bin is often desired,
`21:00-02:59`, `03:00-08:59`, `09:00-14:59`, and `15:00-20:59`, but this is not possible...

```py
# Use 00:00 as center of first bin
bins = [21, 3, 9, 15, 21]
df['time_bin'] = pd.cut(df.index.hour, bins, right=False)

# ValueError: bins must increase monotonically.
```

How can you groupby hour bins so that the 00:00 hour is in the center of the first bin?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `offset` argument of `resample`/`pd.Grouper`. I'll create a simple DataFrame with second resolution and make a column of the index values that way when we `resample` we can see the min and max times in each bin as a proof of concept.

```
import pandas as pd

# Create a sample dataset, a value for each hour in 48 hour
size = 26*60*60
df = pd.DataFrame(range(size), 
                  index=pd.date_range('2020-12-31 11:00:00', periods=size, freq='s'))
df['time'] = df.index
```

---

Resample with 2 hour buckets offset by a single hour. Because the default of `resample`/`pd.Grouper` is:

> `origin='start_day'`: origin is the first day at midnight of the
> timeseries

we can be sure that the offset shifts the bins from [0-2), [2,4)  to [23-1), [1,3), ...

```
res = df.resample('2H', offset='1H')['time'].agg(['min', 'max'])

#                                    min                 max
#2020-12-31 11:00:00 2020-12-31 11:00:00 2020-12-31 12:59:59
#2020-12-31 13:00:00 2020-12-31 13:00:00 2020-12-31 14:59:59
#2020-12-31 15:00:00 2020-12-31 15:00:00 2020-12-31 16:59:59
#2020-12-31 17:00:00 2020-12-31 17:00:00 2020-12-31 18:59:59
#...
#2021-01-01 11:00:00 2021-01-01 11:00:00 2021-01-01 12:59:59
```

The bins (i.e. the index) get labeled with the left edge; you can adjust that after the fact by adding the offset in the resample.

```
from pandas.tseries.frequencies import to_offset

res.index = res.index + to_offset('1H')

#                                    min                 max
#2020-12-31 12:00:00 2020-12-31 11:00:00 2020-12-31 12:59:59
#2020-12-31 14:00:00 2020-12-31 13:00:00 2020-12-31 14:59:59
#2020-12-31 16:00:00 2020-12-31 15:00:00 2020-12-31 16:59:59
#2020-12-31 18:00:00 2020-12-31 17:00:00 2020-12-31 18:59:59
#....
#2021-01-01 12:00:00 2021-01-01 11:00:00 2021-01-01 12:59:59
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to offset some of the hours to make them monotonic for the bins I needed. Below sets hour 23 as -1, hour 22 as -2, and hour 21 as -3.

```py
# Create column of monotonic hours for the desired bins
hours = df.index.hour.to_numpy()
hours[df.index.hour>=21] -= 24
df['hours'] = hours
```

Now we can specify the first bin as `-03:00-02:59`, which puts 00:00 in the center of that bin.

```py
bins = [-3, 3, 9, 15, 21]
df['time_bin'] = pd.cut(df['hours'], bins, right=False)
df.groupby('time_bin').mean()
```

---

Side note for xarray users: This general method may also be used for the `xarray.groupby_bins` method.

```
# Where `ds` is an xarray.Dataset with a `time` coordinate.
HOURS = ds.time.dt.hour
HOURS[HOURS>=21] -= 24
bins = [-3, 3, 9, 15, 21]
ds.groupby_bins(HOURS, bins, right=False).mean()
```

Comment: I see, you had to workaround, to get an offset for the bin edges.