# Speed up conversion of timestamp to datetime Python

Tags: python, datetime, cython, hdf5, pytables

I'm working on making a futures market tick data replay system using python and pytables with a pretty large dataset (+200GB).

As far as I can tell, pytables can only store numpy datetime64 objects for my timestamps.  This is an issue because I need to convert them to datetime objects or pandas timestamps so that the trading module can call methods like time or weekday or month on the incoming data.  trying to convert billions of rows at runtime basically makes the system unusable.

```
pd.to_datetime(my_datetime64)
datetime.datetime(my_datetime64)
```

are both way too slow.

here's how I import my thousands of raw csvs into the pytables store.  Note that the index is in the pandas datetime format which allows me to get information about the timestamp such as time, month, year etc

```
from pandas import HDFStore
store = HDFStore(store_dir)

for file in files:
            df = pd.read_csv("/TickData/"+file)
            df.index = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].apply(str) + " " + df['time'], format = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
            df.drop(['date', 'time'], axis=1, inplace=True)
            store.append('ticks', df, complevel=9, complib='blosc')
```

here's what the data looks like when I read back a chunk with the PyTables table.read method - you can see that the pandas timestamps all got converted into datetime64

```
array([(1220441851000000000, [b'ESU09'], [1281.0], [1]),
       (1226937439000000000, [b'ESU09'], [855.75], [2]),
       (1230045292000000000, [b'ESU09'], [860.0], [1]), ...,
       (1244721917000000000, [b'ESU09'], [943.75], [1]),
       (1244721918000000000, [b'ESU09'], [943.75], [2]),
       (1244721920000000000, [b'ESU09'], [944.0], [15])], 
      dtype=[('index', '<i8'), ('values_block_0', 'S5', (1,)), ('values_block_1', '<f8', (1,)), ('values_block_2', '<i8', (1,))])
```

here's how I read them out of the table in chunks

```
    chunksize = 100000
    nrows = 1000000000
    n_chunks =  nrows//chunksize + 1
    h5f = tables.open_file(store_directory, 'r')
    t = h5f.get_node('/', 'ticks')

    for i in range(n_chunks):
         chunk = t.table.read(i*chunksize, (i+1)*chunksize)
             for c in chunk:
                  #this is where we would convert c[0] which is the timestamp , 
pd.to_datetime(c[0]) or datetime.datetime(c[0]), both are too slow
```

My question ultimately is:

1:  Is there a faster way to convert the datetime64's back into datetimes or pandas timestamps, perhaps something having to do with cython?

OR 2:  is there a way to store the pandas timestamps in the HDF so that they don't need to be converted on read?

Thanks

Comment: How unique are your timestamps and what's the resolution?

Comment: @rrauenza , They're probably 85% unique, millisecond resolution

Comment: Ok, was going to suggest lru memoization if the values repeated a lot.

Comment: BTW, I was unable to get `datetime.datetime(numpy.datetime64(datetime.utcnow()))` to work: `*** TypeError: don't know how to convert scalar number to int`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import numpy
from datetime import datetime

npdt = numpy.datetime64(datetime.utcnow())
dt = npdt.astype(datetime)
```

I found it to be an order of magnitude faster:

```
from datetime import datetime
import numpy
import pandas
import timeit

foo = numpy.datetime64(datetime.utcnow())
print(foo.astype(datetime))
print(pandas.to_datetime(foo))

print(timeit.timeit('foo.astype(datetime)',    setup='import numpy; import pandas; from datetime import datetime; foo = numpy.datetime64(datetime.utcnow())'))
print(timeit.timeit('pandas.to_datetime(foo)', setup='import numpy; import pandas; from datetime import datetime; foo = numpy.datetime64(datetime.utcnow())'))
```

Output:

```
2016-06-10 20:51:11.745616
2016-06-10 20:51:11.745616
1.916042190976441
37.38387820869684
```

Comment: I used this question as a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64