# Get the time spent since midnight in dataframe

Tags: pandas, python-datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe which has a column of type Timestamp. I want to find the time elapsed (in seconds) since midnight as a new column. How to do it in a simple way ?

Eg : 
Input :

```
samples['time']
2018-10-01 00:00:01.000000000
2018-10-01 00:00:12.000000000
```

---

```
type(samples['time'].iloc[0])

<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

Output :

```
samples['time_elapsed']
1
12
```

Comment: It's not difficult but please share some of your data

Comment: I have added an example @JoshFriedlander

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert datatime to milliseconds since midnight UTC or localized in CSV file using Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044264/convert-datatime-to-milliseconds-since-midnight-utc-or-localized-in-csv-file-usi)

Answer (score 5):

Current answers either too complicated or specialized.

```
samples = pd.DataFrame(data=['2018-10-01 00:00:01', '2018-10-01 00:00:12'], columns=['time'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

samples['time_elapsed'] = ((samples['time'] - samples['time'].dt.normalize()) / pd.Timedelta('1 second')).astype(int)

print(samples)
                 time  time_elapsed
0 2018-10-01 00:00:01             1
1 2018-10-01 00:00:12            12
```

- **normalize()** removes the time component from the datetime (moves clock back to midnight).
- **pd.Timedelta('1 s')** sets the unit of measurement, i.e. number of seconds in the timedelta.
- **.astype(int)** casts the decimal number of seconds to int. Use round functionality if that is preferred.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem in my one of my projects and here's how I solved it (assuming your `time` column has already been converted to `Timestamp`):

```
(samples['time'] - samples['time'].dt.normalize()) / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1)
```

The beauty of this approach is that you can change the last part to get seconds, minutes, hours or days elapsed:

```
... / pd.Timedelta(seconds=1) # seconds elapsed
... / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1) # minutes elapsed
... / pd.Timedelta(hours=1)   # hours elapsed
... / pd.Timedelta(days=1)    # days elapsed
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that the date part in each row may be other (not from one
and the same day), so you can not take any "base date" (*midnight*)
for the whole DataFrame, as it can be seen in one of other solutions.

My intention was also not to "contaminate" the source DataFrame
with any intermediate columns, e.g. the *time* (actually date and time)
as string converted to "true" *DateTime*.

Then my proposition is:

- convert the DateTime string to DateTime,
- take the time part from it,
- compute the number of seconds from hour / minute / second
  part.

All the above steps in a dedicated function.

So to do the task, define a function:

```
def secSinceMidnight(datTimStr):
    tt = pd.to_datetime(datTimStr).time()
    return tt.hour * 3600 + tt.minute * 60 + tt.second
```

Then call:

```
samples['Secs'] = samples.time.apply(secSinceMidnight)
```

For source data:

```
samples = pd.DataFrame(data=[
    [ '2018-10-01 00:00:01' ], [ '2018-10-01 00:00:12' ],
    [ '2018-11-02 01:01:10' ], [ '2018-11-04 03:02:15' ] ],
    columns = ['time']);
```

when you print the result, you will see:

```
                  time   Secs
0  2018-10-01 00:00:01      1
1  2018-10-01 00:00:12     12
2  2018-11-02 01:01:10   3670
3  2018-11-04 03:02:15  10935
```

Answer (score 1):

```
datetime = samples['time']

(datetime - datetime.dt.normalize()).dt.total_seconds()
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in Pandas is very simple!

```
midnight = pd.Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00')
print(pd.Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:01.000000000') - midnight).seconds
>
1
```

And by extension we can use an `apply` on a Pandas Series:

```
samples = pd.DataFrame(['2018-10-01 00:00:01.000000000', '2018-10-01 00:00:12.000000000'], columns=['time'])
samples.time = pd.to_datetime(samples.time)
midnight = pd.Timestamp('2018-10-01 00:00:00')
samples['time_elapsed'] = samples['time'].apply(lambda x: (x - midnight).seconds)
samples
>
        time    time_elapsed
0   2018-10-01 00:00:01     1
1   2018-10-01 00:00:12     12
```

Note that the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38044264/convert-datatime-to-milliseconds-since-midnight-utc-or-localized-in-csv-file-usi) use an alternative method: comparing the timestamp to itself converted to a date. This zeros all time data and so is the equivalent of midnight of that day. This method might be slightly more performant.

Comment: This answer assumes all datetimes are on a single declared date (2018-10-01).

Answer (score -1):

We can do :

```
    samples['time'].dt.hour * 3600 + 
    samples['time'].dt.minute * 60 + 
    samples['time'].dt.second
```