# Convert number of miliseconds from midnight from datetime objct using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have datetime index

```
import pandas as pd
sample = ['2021-01-19 15:55:00-05:00',
          '2021-01-19 15:56:00-05:00',
          '2021-01-19 15:56:00-05:00']
sample = pd.to_datetime(sample)
```

I would like to create new column that represents time measured in the number of milliseconds since midnight.

There is one solution for seconds timeframe [Get the time spent since midnight in dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787146/get-the-time-spent-since-midnight-in-dataframe) but I was not able to convert it to miliseconds.

Comment: df['milliseconds'] = df['seconds'] * 1000

Comment: But isn't -05:00 milisecond part of timeframe?

Comment: -05:00 seems to be the deviation from GMT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(sample, columns=['time'])
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df['milliseconds'] = df['time'].apply(lambda x: (x.hour * 3600 + x.minute * 60 + x.second)*1000)

df
```

output

```
    time                        milliseconds
0   2021-01-19 15:55:00-05:00   57300000
1   2021-01-19 15:56:00-05:00   57360000
2   2021-01-19 15:56:00-05:00   57360000
```