# pandas: extract time-of--the day as feature for classification

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series data, with a unix seconds column (among other columns):

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'user': [3,3,3,3,3,6,6,6],
        'timestamp': [1459467971, 1459468020, 1459468026, 1459468031, 
                      1459468036,1513974852, 1513974853, 1513974854]
    }
)
```

The dataset is for classification of some events, some are frequent in the morning, others in the afternoon.

I think `time-of-day` could be an important discriminant as well in this task.

How do I extract number of seconds for time of the day from this?

Note:
I know that using `pandas to_datetime` object would give `HH:MM:SS` as:

```py
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='s')
#df['date'] = df['timestamp'].dt.date
df['time'] = df['timestamp'].dt.time
df
    user      timestamp          time
0   3   2016-03-31 23:46:11     23:46:11
1   3   2016-03-31 23:47:00     23:47:00
2   3   2016-03-31 23:47:06     23:47:06
3   3   2016-03-31 23:47:11     23:47:11
4   3   2016-03-31 23:47:16     23:47:16
5   6   2017-12-22 20:34:12     20:34:12
6   6   2017-12-22 20:34:13     20:34:13
7   6   2017-12-22 20:34:14     20:34:14
```

Isn't there an easy way to pick out the number of seconds representing the time, like this:

```py
    user      timestamp       time-of-day
0   3   2016-03-31 23:46:11       85571
1   3   2016-03-31 23:47:00       85620
2   3   2016-03-31 23:47:06       85626
3   3   2016-03-31 23:47:11       85631
4   3   2016-03-31 23:47:16       85636
5   6   2017-12-22 20:34:12       74052
6   6   2017-12-22 20:34:13       74053
7   6   2017-12-22 20:34:14       74054
```

Comment: There are (24 * 3600) seconds in a day, so you could take your raw unix column and take the remainder when you divide by that number :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787146/get-the-time-spent-since-midnight-in-dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dt.normalize` to subtract the date part:

```
df['time-of-day'] = (df['timestamp'].sub(df['timestamp'].dt.normalize())
                                    .dt.total_seconds().astype(int))
print(df)

# Output
   user           timestamp        date      time  time-of-day
0     3 2016-03-31 23:46:11  2016-03-31  23:46:11        85571
1     3 2016-03-31 23:47:00  2016-03-31  23:47:00        85620
2     3 2016-03-31 23:47:06  2016-03-31  23:47:06        85626
3     3 2016-03-31 23:47:11  2016-03-31  23:47:11        85631
4     3 2016-03-31 23:47:16  2016-03-31  23:47:16        85636
5     6 2017-12-22 20:34:12  2017-12-22  20:34:12        74052
6     6 2017-12-22 20:34:13  2017-12-22  20:34:13        74053
7     6 2017-12-22 20:34:14  2017-12-22  20:34:14        74054
```

**Note**: I'm not sure to use `time-of-day` is relevant as continuous variable. Maybe you should think to discretize into 8 blocks of 3 hours?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `hour`, `minute` and `second` and some basic algebra

```py
df['time-of-day'] = df['timestamp'].dt.hour * 3600 + df['timestamp'].dt.minute * 60 + df['timestamp'].dt.second
```