# checking if a date falls in a dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, python-datetime

I have a dataframe of dates:

```
>>> d.head()
Out[55]: 
0   2010-06-01
1   2010-06-02
2   2010-06-03
3   2010-06-04
4   2010-06-07
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

I am not able to check whether a given date in contained in it:

```
>>> d.iloc[1]
Out[59]: Timestamp('2010-06-02 00:00:00')

>>> d.iloc[1] in d
Out[60]: False

>>> np.datetime64(d.iloc[1]) in d
Out[61]: False

>>> d.iloc[1] in pd.to_datetime(d)
Out[62]: False

>>> pd.to_datetime(d.iloc[1]) in pd.to_datetime(d)
Out[63]: False
```

what's the best to check this?

to answer some of the comments below:

Using values doesnt solve it:

```
>>> d.iloc[1] in d.values
Out[69]: False
```

I dont think it is a matter of iloc returning row not value

```
>>> x= pd.Timestamp('2010-6-2')
>>> x
Out[72]: Timestamp('2010-06-02 00:00:00')
>>> x in d
Out[73]: False
>>> x in pd.to_datetime(d)
Out[74]: False
>>> x in d.values
Out[75]: False
```

Comment: It's `d.iloc[1] in d.values` when you do `smt in d` it searches d's index.

Comment: [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39893420/python-pandas-check-if-date-exists-in-dataframe) is also related.

Comment: @ayhan that didn't help. edited above

Comment: @Garbage Collector the solution in that post didnt help as i have shown

Comment: OK reopened....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. You are comparing the first value of a `pd.Series` against the values in the column, which of course will be `True`.

The reason I believe your comparison does not work is because the [`in` operator acting on `pd.Series` checks for existence in the *series index*](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19/gotchas.html#using-the-in-operator), not the series values itself. Applying `set` ensures that the series values are used fo the comparison.

```
# df
#     date
# 0   2010-06-01
# 1   2010-06-02
# 2   2010-06-03
# 3   2010-06-04
# 4   2010-06-07

# convert date column to datetime
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.date[1] in set(df.date)
```

Comment: @ jp_data_analysis  sorry didnt seem to help - i included my results in the edit above

Comment: @dayum have you tried applying `pd.to_datetime` to the value you are checking? this was what was advised in the link @GarbaceCollector provided.

Comment: @ jp_data_analysis yup thats been reported above

Comment: @ jp_data_analysis yes that worked. I just posted a detailed answer as to why that seemed to work, and another solution to this

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible answer i got on trial and error, not sure if I am missing something.

Checking d shows that it is a dtype datetime64[ns]

```
>>> d.head()
Out[55]: 
0   2010-06-01
1   2010-06-02
2   2010-06-03
3   2010-06-04
4   2010-06-07
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Same happens on d.values

```
>>> d.values
Out[76]: 
array(['2010-05-31T20:00:00.000000000-0400', '2010-06-01T20:00:00.000000000-0400',.....], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

But checking only one of them changes it to timestamp.

```
>>> d.iloc[1]
Out[82]: Timestamp('2010-06-02 00:00:00')
```

So i did this which worked:

```
>>> x= pd.Timestamp('2010-6-2')
>>> x
Out[72]: Timestamp('2010-06-02 00:00:00')
>>> np.datetime64(x) in d.values
Out[77]: True
```

Checking @jp_data_analysis suggestion of using set also worked as it keeps the format to Timestamp

```
>>> set(d.iloc[:])
Out[81]: 
{Timestamp('2015-10-13 00:00:00'),
 Timestamp('2011-07-18 00:00:00'),......

>>> x in set(d.iloc[:])
Out[83]: True
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do the following, with `.isin` (note that .isin does require a list as input):

```
df.date = pd.to_datetime(df.date)

df.date.isin([df.date.iloc[1]])
```