# Python to mysql 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I'm trying to load a pandas dataframe to a mysql table using Sqlalchemy.

I connect using; `engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://user:password@ip:port/db")`

I am then simply running;

```
df.to_sql(con=engine, name='Table', if_exists='append', index=False, chunksize=10000);
```

I keep getting the error

```
AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

This worked fine when I used older versions and did this via pymysql, not sqlalchemy

I can't find anything online to help, any ideas.

thanks,

Comment: This looks relevant: https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/issues/499

Answer (score 4):

I converted my **timestamp** object into `ts.to_pydatetime()` before passing it to the cursor and that solved the attribute error.

See this answer for different ways of converting timestamps:
[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered the same issue when I tried to insert a very large dataframe(`df`) into MySQL which has a column(`df['date_']`) with `'datetime64[ns]'` dtype.

The date_ column is initially converted to `datetime64[ns]` using `pd.to_datetime(df[date_])`. I found that the datatype of `df['date_']` is an  `object` and not `datetime64[ns]`. So, I took a small chunk of data from the table to debug & found that the dtype was `datetime64[ns]` which is correct & even the data got inserted into the database. Hence, there were definitely some rows that failed to convert into `datetime64[ns]` which I believe is the reason behind the error.

However, casting this column as string(shown below) solved the issue for me.

```
df['date_'] = df['date_'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Change the type to str to commit is the right answer. Keep the model side to db.DateTime is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Check the datatypes of your data frame using `df.dtypes` and make sure your columns are the correct datatype. If you have a column that you expect to be timestamps, make sure it's datatype is `datetime64[ns]`. If it is `object` (or even something else), you can probably convert it using the [`pandas.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) function.

I was just having this same issue. In my case there was a column I was trying to write that contained timestamps but it's datatype was `object`. After conversion with `df[colname] = pd.to_datetime(df[colname])` I was able to successfully write it using the pymysql driver and sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 0):

I was using a parametized insert query when I encountered this issue.  Converting to pd.to_datetime didnt solve the issue for me, but casting the pandas Timestamp object as a str worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. Found the best solution was to just transform all timestamp-like columns as string.

```
df = df.apply(lambda col: col.astype(str) if col.dtype == 'datetime64[ns]' else col)
```