# mdates.DateLocator() raising NotImplemented error

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am still working on getting nice rounded datatime in xticks:
[rounding datetimes in xticks matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46550153/rounding-datetimes-in-xticks-matplotlib)

So the answer was fine, and I could use

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator())
```

to get round hours in the xticks.

However, if I simply do

```
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DateLocator())
```

it gives:

```
  File "/python/anaconda-2.7.11-64/lib/python2.7/site-packages    /matplotlib/ticker.py", line 1289, in __call__
    raise NotImplementedError('Derived must override')
NotImplementedError: Derived must override
```

Is it really impossible to change HourLocator() to DateLocator() ? 
I am using
`matplotlib.__version__'2.0.2'`

Comment: maybe try `AutoDateLocator`? or if you know that you want months or years for example, try `MonthLocator` or `YearLocator`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not meant do use `DateLocator` by itself. This is the baseclass of all other locators for dates that matplotlib provides. The matplotlib dates API page [lists the possible locators](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#date-tickers) to be

> Here are all the date tickers:
>
> - MinuteLocator: locate minutes
> - HourLocator: locate hours
> - DayLocator: locate specifed days of the month
> - WeekdayLocator: Locate days of the week, e.g., MO, TU
> - MonthLocator: locate months, e.g., 7 for july
> - YearLocator: locate years that are multiples of base
> - RRuleLocator: locate using a matplotlib.dates.rrulewrapper. The rrulewrapper is a simple wrapper around a dateutil.rrule (dateutil) which allow almost arbitrary date tick specifications. See rrule example.
> - AutoDateLocator: On autoscale, this class picks the best MultipleDateLocator to set the view limits and the tick locations.

Choose any one of those and you will be fine.

In addition to those mentionned, there is also a `SecondLocator` and 
 a `MicrosecondLocator` available, which are not (well) documented.

Comment: how do I set the maximum number of desired ticks when using the autodatelocator?

Comment: The [AutoDateLocator](https://matplotlib.org/api/dates_api.html#matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator) has an argument `maxticks`. Does it not work?

Comment: It does work if I do                          mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=total_days, maxticks=total_days)

Comment: However, when I input the same value for minticks and maxticks, I get an error UserWarning: AutoDateLocator was unable to pick an appropriate interval for this date range. It may be necessary to add an interval value to the AutoDateLocator's intervald dictionary. Defaulting to 10000.
  ' Defaulting to {0}.'.format(interval))

Comment: The problem arises when plotting multiple times on the same axis. How do I get the current xlim() in datetime format?

Comment: You should give the AutoDateLocator some freedom to choose some good locations (hence the name *Auto*). Setting min and max to the same value may result in strange things. This is what the warning is telling you. Note that its not an error; a warning can be ignored if the result is otherwise fine. The limits of the axes are obtained via `ax.get_xlim()`.