# Guidelines for using various datetime classes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

There are several date/time related classes like `datetime.date`, `datetime.datetime`, `pandas.Timestamp`, `numpy.datetime64`. Are there some general guidelines when to use one over the other in a project?

What are the advantages of each?

Should I avoid using python native `datetime` objects if I use `pandas` most of the time?

My use case:
I have a project which uses daily financial price data, I use pandas in most functions, but I have also some functions which just use a `list` of `datetime.date`. I feel like it would be good to unify my data types for the whole project.

Comment: [Here's a handy chart to show how confusing this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21916253/4799172). The answer below, from Panda's creator; "Welcome to hell" :P

Comment: In fact, I've re-read that thread and there's a new answer from Oct that goes into [a lot of detail](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921593/4799172). I think it's a suitable dupe target because it really is a messy topic; I imagine the guidelines is try pick through and find what is most suitable for you.