# How to convert Pandas DataFrame column from Pandas datetime64[ns] to Pyodbc SQL_Timestamp

Tags: python, dataframe, odbc, pyodbc, ms-access-2016

I am trying to populate Pandas Dataframe into **empty** **MS Access 2016** table via pyodbc. I get the following error message when I try to insert Dataframes into Access: *pyodbc.dataerror: ('22008', [ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Datetime field overflow*.

Research showed that MS Access **Date/Time** datatypes correspond to ODBC **SQL_TIMESTAMP** datatypes.

I tried the following to convert datetime64[ns] to SQL_TIMESTAMP:

```
import datetime
cursor.execute("INSERT sql statement...VALUES(?)", datetime.datetime(order_date))
```

However, I get this error: **TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp).**

What do I need to do in order to successfully populate Pandas/Numpy's datetime64[ns] values into Access tables? Do I need to convert them into SQL_TIMESTAMP and how?

---

**EDIT:**
I tried running Gord Thompson's solution below and I am running into this error:

```
import datetime
```

`dt = dt64_to_datetime(dt_ns)`

`>> AttributeError:'datetime' has no attribute 'utcfromtimestamp'`

What is the reason behind this error?  *(Tested on pyodbc 4.0.17, Python 3.6.2, MS Access 2016)*

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you get from `print(repr(order_date))` and `print(order_date.dtype)`.

Comment: I used `from datetime import datetime`. If you just `import datetime` then you'll probably need to use `datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp`.

Comment: @ Gord Thompson - I followed your solution, but I get the following error: `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument`. I believe this is because an input value is `numpy.datetime64('NaT')`.  What can I do about NaT values?

Answer (score 1):

> What do I need to do in order to successfully populate Pandas/Numpy's datetime64[ns] values into Access tables? Do I need to convert them into SQL_TIMESTAMP and how?

As illustrated in [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921593/2144390), you'll probably need to convert the `numpy.datetime64` values to Python `datetime` values, perhaps like this:

```python
def dt64_to_datetime(dt64):
    if np.isnat(dt64):
        return None
    else:
        unix_epoch = np.datetime64(0, 's')
        one_second = np.timedelta64(1, 's')
        seconds_since_epoch = (dt64 - unix_epoch) / one_second
        return datetime.utcfromtimestamp(seconds_since_epoch)
```

Example usage:

```python
dt_ns = np.datetime64('2017-10-24 05:34:20.123456').astype('datetime64[ns]')
print(repr(dt_ns))  # numpy.datetime64('2017-10-24T05:34:20.123456000')
print(f'dt_ns.dtype: {dt_ns.dtype}')  # dt_ns.dtype: datetime64[ns]
dt = dt64_to_datetime(dt_ns)
print(repr(dt))  # datetime.datetime(2017, 10, 24, 5, 34, 20, 123456)

sql = "UPDATE tablename SET datetimefield = ? WHERE id=1"
params = (dt,)
crsr.execute(sql, params)
```

(Tested with pyodbc 4.0.21 and Access 2010.)

Comment: @ Gord Thompson - Do you know the difference between Pandas/Numpy datetime64 and **datetime64[ns]** values?

Comment: @Mook - I didn't, but it also doesn't seem to make a difference in this case. I have updated my answer.

Comment: @ Gord Thompson - I am confused with your solution. When I print the datetime64[ns] values, it looks like this: **2017-01-01**. Also, I am trying to insert the Order_date column values into Access by using SQL INSERT statement.

Comment: @Mook - I'm confused, too, because `np.datetime64('2017-01-01').astype('datetime64[ns]')` prints as `numpy.datetime64('2017-01-01T00:00:00.000000000')`, and it also works for the UPDATE (after being converted to `datetime`).

Comment: @ Gord Thompson - I updated my question to try to clear up some confusion. I am trying to populate this Pandas column into an empty Access table. So SQL UPDATE statement may not work.

Comment: @Mook - UPDATE was just an example. INSERT works, too.

Comment: @ Gord Thompson - I followed your solution and I am getting an INVALID ARGUMENT error for the `return` statement. I believe this is because of `numpy.datetime64('NaT').` How can I convert `NaT` values into Python `datetime` values?

Comment: @Mook re: "How can I convert `NaT` values into Python `datetime` values?" - AFAIK Python `datetime` objects do not have an equivalent to the 'NaT' (not-a-time) value of a NumPy `datetime64` object, so a direct conversion is not possible. For the purposes of inserting into a database the most obvious choice would be have the conversion function use `np.isnat()` to test for a 'NaT' and return `None` so a NULL would be inserted into the column. If `None` is not an option (e.g., if the column is not NULLable) then some arbitrary past or future datetime value might have to do.

Comment: @ Gord Thompson - I tried your advice, but `isnat()` is throwing error for me. `Pd.isnull()` is working instead. I tried the following code to replace `NaT` with `None`, but there are no changes: `df.loc[df['Register_Date'].isnull(), 'Register_Date'] = None`. Do you know why?