# How to convert Pandas NaN to NaT

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert NaN (dtype: float64) values in a Pandas DataFrame column into NaT values.

**Please** note that I have several DataFrames with the same *Order_date* column. Some *Order_date* columns' dtypes are float64 (filled with NaN) while others' dtypes are datetime64[ns] (filled with NaT).

I tried the following:

```
df.loc[:,'Order_date'] = df.loc[:,'Order_date'].astype(np.datetime64).fillna(pd.NaT)
```

However, I get an Error result:

```
TypeError: cannot astype a datatimelike from [datetime64[ns]] to [datetime64].
```

What is reason behind this error? I think the error is due to how several Order_date columns in some DataFrames have NaT values (datetime64[ns]). **What can I do to successfully convert only the Order_date columns with NaN values into NaT values in Pandas and leave the remaining Order_date columns that already have NaT values as is?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert Pandas DataFrame column from Pandas datetime64\[ns\] to Pyodbc SQL\_Timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47643804/how-to-convert-pandas-dataframe-column-from-pandas-datetime64ns-to-pyodbc-sql)

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. This question is asking how to convert NaN to NaT values.

Answer (score 0):

I might be misunderstanding the requirements of the problem, but wouldn't

```
df['Order_date'].fillna(pd.NaT, inplace=True)
```

do the job?

Comment: I tried your solution, but it does not work. It converts NaN values to _None_ values. I get the following error: pyodbc.DataError:   **('22008', '[22008] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Datetime field overflow (SQLExecDirectW)')**

Comment: If you can add a small snippet of your dataframe that illustrates your point, I can probably find a way around the problem. I am afraid I am misunderstanding the problem at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

What about using `pd.to_datetime()`? Like so:

```
pd.to_datetime(df.loc[:,'Order_date'])
```

Should return `pd.NaT` instead of `np.NaN`