# How to populate Pandas datetime64[ns] values into MS Access

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pyodbc

I have several DataFrames that have *Order_date* column. In all DataFrames, the *Order_date* columns' dtypes are datetime64[ns]. Please note that these columns are filled with valid dates and NaT values.

An example of how Order_date column looks like when printed:

```
   Order_date
```

`1 2017-01-01
 2 NaT
 3 NaT
 4 NaT 
 5 2017-10-22`

I am trying to populate these columns of DataFrames into MS Access table **via pyodbc**.

I get the following error:

**pyodbc.DataError: ('22008', '[22008] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Datetime field overflow (SQLExecDirectW)')**

After research, I noticed that the Date/Time datatype for MS Access 2016 corresponds with ODBC datatype **SQL_TIMESTAMP**.

So, I tried the following to convert datetime64[ns] to SQL_TIMESTAMP:

```
import datetime
cursor.execute("SQL statement...VALUES(?)", datetime.datetime(order_date))
```

However, I get this error: **TypeError: an integer is required (got type Timestamp).**

What can I do to successfully populate Pandas/Numpy datetime64[ns] values into MS Access table? How can I convert datetime64[ns] values into SQL_TIMESTAMP?

Comment: same question ah?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47666800/how-to-convert-pandas-nan-to-nat/47666975#47666975

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC - you were almost there. You just have to assign a Series returned by `pd.to_datetime` back to column:

```
df['Order_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order_date'], errors='coerce')
```

Comment: Thank you. Your solution converts the columns into NaT. I have another question: do you know how I can convert Pandas datetime64[ns] values into MS Access SQL_TIMESTAMP values? Please note that I updated my question above.

Comment: @Mook, when you update a question you make a given answers invalid. Please ask a new question instead and consider accepting an answer...

Comment: @ MaxU - I accepted your answer. Thank you once again for your answer.