# Cannot convert from an iterable of Python `datetime` objects to an array of Numpy `datetime64` objects using `fromiter()`. Bug?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, datetime

I'm using Python 3.6.2.

I've learnt from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64) how to convert between the standard `datetime` type to `np.datetime64` type, as follows.

```
dt = datetime.now()
print(dt)
print(np.datetime64(dt))
```

Output:

```
2017-12-19 17:20:12.743969
2017-12-19T17:20:12.743969
```

But I can't convert an iterable of standard `datetime` objects into a Numpy array. The following code ...

```
np.fromiter([dt], dtype=np.datetime64)
```

... gives the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-46e4618bda89> in <module>()
----> 1 np.fromiter([dt], dtype=np.datetime64)

TypeError: Cannot cast datetime.datetime object from metadata [us] to  according to the rule 'same_kind'
```

However, using `np.asarray()` works.

```
np.asarray([dt])
```

Output:

```
array([datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 19, 17, 20, 12, 743969)], dtype=object)
```

Might this be a bug with either `np.fromiter()` or `np.datetime64`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may just be a matter of setting the datetime units:

```
In [368]: dt = datetime.now()
In [369]: dt
Out[369]: datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 19, 12, 48, 45, 143287)
```

Default action for `np.array` (don't really need `fromiter` with a list) is to create an object dtype array:

```
In [370]: np.array([dt,dt])
Out[370]: 
array([datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 19, 12, 48, 45, 143287),
       datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 19, 12, 48, 45, 143287)], dtype=object)
```

Looks like plain 'datetime64' produces days:

```
In [371]: np.array([dt,dt], dtype='datetime64')
Out[371]: array(['2017-12-19', '2017-12-19'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

and specifying the units:

```
In [373]: np.array([dt,dt], dtype='datetime64[m]')
Out[373]: array(['2017-12-19T12:48', '2017-12-19T12:48'], dtype='datetime64[m]')
```

This also works with `fromiter`.

```
In [374]: np.fromiter([dt,dt], dtype='datetime64[m]')
Out[374]: array(['2017-12-19T12:48', '2017-12-19T12:48'], dtype='datetime64[m]')
In [384]: x= np.fromiter([dt,dt], dtype='M8[us]')
In [385]: x
Out[385]: array(['2017-12-19T12:48:45.143287', '2017-12-19T12:48:45.143287'], dtype='datetime64[us]')
```

I've learned to use the string name of the datetime64, which allows me to specify the units, rather than the most generic `np.datetime64`.

Comment: Thank you. I think the problem was that I didn't specify the resolution (unit). Using the string form works.