# Numpy isnat() returns value error on datetime objects

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Have been working through options listed in [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64); however, numpy's isnat() seems to not recognize a datetime object, or I'm missing some other kind of datetime object that the function requires for input.

Here's an overview of the dataframe:

```
>>> time_data.head()
     Date          Name               In AM              Out AM  \
0  2017-12-04  AUSTIN LEWIS 1900-01-01 07:03:11 1900-01-01 12:01:50   
1  2017-12-05  AUSTIN LEWIS 1900-01-01 05:24:07 1900-01-01 12:08:21   
2  2017-12-06  AUSTIN LEWIS 1900-01-01 11:58:32                 NaT   
3  2017-12-07  AUSTIN LEWIS 1900-01-01 08:31:23 1900-01-01 12:49:51   
4  2017-12-11  AUSTIN LEWIS 1900-01-01 06:55:21 1900-01-01 12:02:08   

            In PM              Out PM Sick Time  
0 1900-01-01 12:28:52 1900-01-01 17:34:53       NaT  
1 1900-01-01 12:35:12 1900-01-01 16:15:17       NaT  
2                 NaT 1900-01-01 23:59:01       NaT  
3 1900-01-01 13:18:34 1900-01-01 18:10:35       NaT  
4 1900-01-01 12:30:49 1900-01-01 17:39:54       NaT  

>>> time_data.dtypes
Date                 object
Name                 object
In AM        datetime64[ns]
Out AM       datetime64[ns]
In PM        datetime64[ns]
Out PM       datetime64[ns]
Sick Time    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

>>> type(time_data['In AM'][3])
<class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>

>>> type(time_data['In AM'][3].to_datetime())
<type 'datetime.datetime'>
```

`if np.isnat(time_data['Out AM'][row].to_datetime()) & np.isnat(time_data['In PM'][row].to_datetime()):`

Throws "ValueError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta"

What am I missing here?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also just convert everything from the beginning using `pd.to_datetime` on your wanted datetime columns:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date' : [
        '2017-12-04',
        '2017-12-05',
        '2017-12-06',
        '2017-12-07',
        '2017-12-11'
    ],
    'name' : ['AUSTIN LEWIS'] * 5,
    'in_am' : [
        '1900-01-01 07:03:11',
        '1900-01-01 05:24:07',
        '1900-01-01 11:58:32',
        '1900-01-01 08:31:23',
        '1900-01-01 06:55:21'
    ],
    'out_am' : [
        '1900-01-01 12:01:50',
        '1900-01-01 12:08:21',
        '',
        '1900-01-01 12:49:51',
        '1900-01-01 12:02:08'
    ],
    'in_pm' : [
        '1900-01-01 12:28:52',
        '1900-01-01 12:35:12',
        '',
        '1900-01-01 13:18:34',
        '1900-01-01 12:30:49'
    ],
    'out_pm' : [
        '1900-01-01 17:34:53',
        '1900-01-01 16:15:17',
        '1900-01-01 23:59:01',
        '1900-01-01 18:10:35',
        '1900-01-01 17:39:54'
    ],
    'sick_time' : [''] * 5
})
```

[image: input]

```
# all dtypes should be object
df.dtypes
```

[image: dtypes]

```
# convert to datetimes
for col in df.columns.drop('name').tolist():
    df[col] = pd.to_datetime(df[col])

# name should be only object
df.dtypes
```

[image: new dtypes]

```
# np.isnat should now work
np.isnat(df.loc[:, df.dtypes == 'datetime64[ns]'])
```

[image: output]

Comment: Ahhh, finally! Thank you @Ian-thompson!  I had already used `time_data[nt] = time_data[nt].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%H:%M:%S.%f')` to convert all the datetime columns, though for some reason, np.isnan() only likes .loc indexing :shrug:

`>>> np.isnat(time_data.loc[2:2, 'Out AM'])
2    True
Name: Out AM, dtype: bool
>>> time_data.loc[2, 'Out AM']
NaT
>>> np.isnat(time_data.loc[2, 'Out AM'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<debugger>", line 1, in <module>
np.isnat(time_data.loc[2, 'Out AM'])
ValueError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta.`

Answer (score 6):

Ugh, that's a really bad error message!  `np.isnat` ("is not a time") only works with *numpy's* datetimes.  The typical use for a ufunc is with an array of `np.datetime64` or `np.timedelta64` dtype:

```
>>> dt = datetime.now()
>>> np.isnat(np.array([dt], dtype=np.datetime64))
array([False])
>>> np.isnat(np.array([dt], dtype=object))
TypeError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta.
```

Refer to the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnat.html) for supported input types.

Comment: I was just doing the same observation, +1
`>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.isnat
<ufunc 'isnat'>
>>> np.isnat(np.datetime64("NaT"))
True
>>> nat = np.datetime64("NaT")
>>> nat
numpy.datetime64('NaT')
>>>`

@OP Just convert them using `np.datetime64`

Comment: Bizarrely, this works on everything except NaT!

`>>> np.isnat(np.datetime64(time_data['Out AM'][2]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<debugger>", line 1, in <module>
np.isnat(np.datetime64(time_data['Out AM'][2]))
ValueError: cannot convert float NaN to integer

>>> time_data['Out AM'][2]
NaT`

Comment: `np.isnat(np.datetime64('NaT'))` returns True for me.  Are you sure you don't have NaN in there not NaT ?

Comment: Yup.  Certain. Depending on how I index and what conversions I use, the field seems to jump from Datetime.datetime, to Pandas timestamp to numpy datetime64.  Ugh.