# ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta

Tags: python, dataframe

Considering the below example in df I have `ts` as datetime.

```
df.dtypes

parts_produced             int64
event                     object
c                         object
ts                datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

> Now, I am trying to check if ts is empty because it is when I do a
> `shift(-1)` on a column `ts` for the last record.

If I check `np.isnat(ts)`, I get :

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta.
```

Debugging step:

```
p ts
Timestamp('2020-09-10 00:10:00')

np.isnat(ts)
*** TypeError: ufunc 'isnat' is only defined for datetime and timedelta.
```

Comment: Please post sample input and expected output for better understanding.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy isnat() returns value error on datetime objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48194470/numpy-isnat-returns-value-error-on-datetime-objects)