# Why does the format change when converting DatetimeIndex to np.array?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe and I want to convert it to a numpy array.

```
>>> df.index
DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-28 01:00:00', '2018-02-28 01:01:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:02:00', '2018-02-28 01:03:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:04:00', '2018-02-28 01:05:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:06:00', '2018-02-28 01:07:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:08:00', '2018-02-28 01:09:00',
            ...
            '2018-02-28 17:25:00', '2018-02-28 17:26:00',
            '2018-02-28 17:27:00', '2018-02-28 17:28:00',
            '2018-02-28 17:29:00', '2018-02-28 17:30:00',
            '2018-02-28 17:31:00', '2018-02-28 17:32:00',
            '2018-02-28 17:33:00', '2018-02-28 17:34:00'],
            dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date', length=995, freq='T')
```

But if I just simply try to convert it, the format changes.

```
>>> np.array( ohlc.index )
array(['2018-02-28T01:00:00.000000000', '2018-02-28T01:01:00.000000000',
    '2018-02-28T01:02:00.000000000', '2018-02-28T01:03:00.000000000',
    '2018-02-28T01:04:00.000000000', '2018-02-28T01:05:00.000000000',
    ...
    '2018-02-28T17:30:00.000000000', '2018-02-28T17:31:00.000000000',
    '2018-02-28T17:32:00.000000000', '2018-02-28T17:33:00.000000000',
    '2018-02-28T17:34:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

It seems `2018-02-28 01:00:00` and `2018-02-28T01:00:00.000000000` are not the same. How can I keep the format?

Comment: Why is the format important? Numpy isn't actually storing a string of 0's. It's just a string representation for display purposes, e.g. 15.0000001 might sometimes be displayed instead of 15.0 due to float representation. You can easily set formatting when you need to `print` an array. Is that what you need?

Comment: @jpp Thank you for the comment. Actually, I want to make a dictionary the keys of which are the same as df.index. ```dic_timeToIndex = dict(zip( np.array(df.index), array_anotherIndex ))``` but in this case, the format changes and so does the ```keys```. That's why I want to keep the format.

Comment: I still don't understand. Why is it not a good idea to have your dictionary keys as timestamps? There is no requirement that dictionary keys must be strings / specially formatted for printing.

Comment: I've added a solution where your keys are timestamps.

Comment: @jpp Thank you! After reading your comments, I looked into my code again and realized that using timestamps is simpler than my original idea. I appreciate you helping me! :)

Comment: Meta on this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364079/how-to-handle-equivalent-answers-but-different-explanations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `2018-02-28 01:00:00` is `2018-02-28T01:00:00.000000000` as represenation of `datetime64[ns]`.

Under the hood datetimes are long integers as `nanoseconds` since epoch called `unix time`:

```
c = a.values.astype(np.int64)
print (c)
[1519779600000000000 1519779660000000000 1519779720000000000
 1519779780000000000 1519779840000000000 1519779900000000000
 1519779960000000000 1519780020000000000 1519780080000000000
 1519780140000000000 1519838700000000000 1519838760000000000
 1519838820000000000 1519838880000000000 1519838940000000000
 1519839000000000000 1519839060000000000 1519839120000000000
 1519839180000000000 1519839240000000000]
```

You can also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704307/2901002) for more info.

---

If want `string`s:

```
b = df.index.astype(str).values
```

Or:

```
b = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

---

```
print (b)
['2018-02-28 01:00:00' '2018-02-28 01:01:00' '2018-02-28 01:02:00'
 '2018-02-28 01:03:00' '2018-02-28 01:04:00' '2018-02-28 01:05:00'
 '2018-02-28 01:06:00' '2018-02-28 01:07:00' '2018-02-28 01:08:00'
 '2018-02-28 01:09:00' '2018-02-28 17:25:00' '2018-02-28 17:26:00'
 '2018-02-28 17:27:00' '2018-02-28 17:28:00' '2018-02-28 17:29:00'
 '2018-02-28 17:30:00' '2018-02-28 17:31:00' '2018-02-28 17:32:00'
 '2018-02-28 17:33:00' '2018-02-28 17:34:00']
```

Another way is cast to `second` precision with floor if exist `ms`, `us`, `ns`.

```
b = df.index.values.astype('datetime64[s]')
print (b)
['2018-02-28T01:00:00' '2018-02-28T01:01:00' '2018-02-28T01:02:00'
 '2018-02-28T01:03:00' '2018-02-28T01:04:00' '2018-02-28T01:05:00'
 '2018-02-28T01:06:00' '2018-02-28T01:07:00' '2018-02-28T01:08:00'
 '2018-02-28T01:09:00' '2018-02-28T17:25:00' '2018-02-28T17:26:00'
 '2018-02-28T17:27:00' '2018-02-28T17:28:00' '2018-02-28T17:29:00'
 '2018-02-28T17:30:00' '2018-02-28T17:31:00' '2018-02-28T17:32:00'
 '2018-02-28T17:33:00' '2018-02-28T17:34:00']
```

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, is not necessary converting, but it depends of requirement of keys:

```
i = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-28 01:00:00', '2018-02-28 01:01:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:02:00', '2018-02-28 01:03:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:04:00', '2018-02-28 01:05:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:06:00', '2018-02-28 01:07:00',
            '2018-02-28 01:08:00', '2018-02-28 01:09:00'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index=i)
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2018-02-28 01:00:00, 2018-02-28 01:01:00, 2018-02-28 01:02:00, 
        2018-02-28 01:03:00, 2018-02-28 01:04:00, 2018-02-28 01:05:00, 
        2018-02-28 01:06:00, 2018-02-28 01:07:00, 2018-02-28 01:08:00, 
        2018-02-28 01:09:00]
```

Selecting by `Timestamp`s:

```
d = dict(zip(df.index, np.arange(10)))
{Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:00:00'): 0, Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:01:00'): 1, 
 Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:02:00'): 2, Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:03:00'): 3, 
 Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:04:00'): 4, Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:05:00'): 5, 
 Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:06:00'): 6, Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:07:00'): 7, 
 Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:08:00'): 8, Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:09:00'): 9}

print (d[pd.Timestamp('2018-02-28 01:00:00')])
0

print (d[pd.to_datetime('2018-02-28 01:00:00')])
```

Selecting by strings, simpliest:

```
d1 = dict(zip(df.index.astype(str).values, np.arange(10)))
{'2018-02-28 01:00:00': 0, '2018-02-28 01:01:00': 1, '2018-02-28 01:02:00': 2, 
 '2018-02-28 01:03:00': 3, '2018-02-28 01:04:00': 4, '2018-02-28 01:05:00': 5, 
 '2018-02-28 01:06:00': 6, '2018-02-28 01:07:00': 7, '2018-02-28 01:08:00': 8, 
 '2018-02-28 01:09:00': 9}

d1 = dict(zip(df.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), np.arange(10)))
{'2018-02-28 01:00:00': 0, '2018-02-28 01:01:00': 1, '2018-02-28 01:02:00': 2, 
 '2018-02-28 01:03:00': 3, '2018-02-28 01:04:00': 4, '2018-02-28 01:05:00': 5, 
 '2018-02-28 01:06:00': 6, '2018-02-28 01:07:00': 7, '2018-02-28 01:08:00': 8, 
 '2018-02-28 01:09:00': 9}

print (d1['2018-02-28 01:00:00'])
0
```

---

```
print (dict(zip(df.index.values.astype('datetime64[s]'), np.arange(10))))
{numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:00:00'): 0, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:01:00'): 1, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:02:00'): 2, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:03:00'): 3, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:04:00'): 4, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:05:00'): 5, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:06:00'): 6, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:07:00'): 7, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:08:00'): 8, 
 numpy.datetime64('2018-02-28T01:09:00'): 9}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the information you have provided, you don't need to convert `datetime` objects to strings. In fact, no type conversion is necessary.

Where possible, keep your data, inputs and outputs structured. Strings are often only useful for I/O.

```
import pandas as pd
from dateutil import parser

idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2018-02-28 01:00:00', '2018-02-28 01:01:00',
                        '2018-02-28 01:02:00', '2018-02-28 01:03:00',
                        '2018-02-28 01:04:00', '2018-02-28 01:05:00'],
                       dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='date')

values = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

d = dict(zip(idx, values))

x = parser.parse('2018-02-28 01:02:00') 
# equivalently, x = pd.to_datetime('2018-02-28 01:02:00')

d[x]  # 3
```

Consider this fundamental problem with storing your keys as strings:

```
x = parser.parse('2018-02-28 01:02:00')
y = parser.parse('2018-02-28 1:02:00')

print(x == y)          # True

x_str = '2018-02-28 01:02:00'
y_str = '2018-02-28 1:02:00'

print(x_str == y_str)  # False
```