# How to convert numpy and pandas datetime objects to numeric?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

Using timestamps, datetimes is not always convenient. Some programs expect simple numeric input. When pandas Timestamps are collected in a pandas.Series it is easy to convert them to numeric values and back.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

age = [30, 31, 31]
date = [Timestamp('2001-02-10 00:01:00'),
 Timestamp('2001-11-12 00:01:00'),
 Timestamp('2002-02-27 00:01:00')]

df = pd.DataFrame({'age': age, 'date': date})

pd.to_numeric(df.date)
0     981763260000000000
1    1005523260000000000
2    1014768060000000000
```

Though converting a single pandas or numpy datetime object or a timedelta to numeric does not work like that.

```
pd.to_numeric(Timestamp('2001-02-10 00:01:00'))
pd.to_numeric([Timestamp('2001-02-10 00:01:00')])
pd.to_numeric([numpy.datetime64('2001-02-10T00:01:00.000000000')])
pd.to_numeric([pd.Timedelta('365 days')])
# all give:
#> TypeError: Invalid object type at position 0
```

What are proper ways to convert these types to numeric types?

Comment: @jpp: I don't want the generate a Series or DataFrame just to convert a Datetime to a numeric value. The first two questions address Series and DataFrames. The third question is about conversion between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64. It is actually not about numeric values at all. The last question is somewhat what I am looking for, but also very specific. So, I don't think this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64). In particular, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21916253/9209546).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `ts.value` attribute of the timestamp `ts`:

```
ts = Timestamp('2001-02-10 00:01:00')
print(ts.value)
#981763260000000000
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the methods of the [pandas.Timestamp](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.html) class:

```
>>> Timestamp('2001-02-10 00:01:00').timestamp()
981763260.0
```

Comment: The return value of `.timestamp()` is inconsistent with `pd.to_numeric()`.

Answer (score 0):

Converting timedelta to numeric:

```
x = pd.Timedelta('365 days')
x
#Timedelta('365 days 00:00:00')

type(x)
#pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta

y = x / np.timedelta64(1, 'D')
y
#365.0

type(y)
#float
```