# Plot rectangles in Matplotlib with datetime data

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib

I have the following problem: I have a dataframe with a datetime index and columns that either contain float or boolean values, like this:

```
                     TAG_2552  TAG_2526
timestamp
2018-06-17 14:41:48      50.0      True
2018-06-17 14:41:49      51.0      True
2018-06-17 14:41:50      52.0      True
2018-06-17 14:41:51      49.0      True
2018-06-17 14:41:52      55.0      False
2018-06-17 14:41:53      50.0      False
2018-06-17 14:41:54      48.0      False
2018-06-17 14:41:55      54.0      False
2018-06-17 14:41:56      53.0      True
2018-06-17 14:41:57      50.0      True
```

I would like to plot this, which is not a problem for the float values. For the booleans, I would like to draw rectangles whenever they are `True`. I tried to use [matplotlib.collections](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/api/span_regions.html#sphx-glr-gallery-api-span-regions-py) to do so .

I tried

```
df['datetime']=df.index
collection = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(df['datetime'].dt.date, ymin=0, ymax=1, where=df['TAG_2526']==True, facecolor='green', alpha=.5)
```

(and other variants) but this did not work.

It is possible to create a collection using

```
df['timedelta'] = df['datetime']-df['datetime'][0]
collection2 = collections.BrokenBarHCollection.span_where(myProc9['timedelta'].astype('timedelta64[ns]')/np.timedelta64(1,'s'), ymin=0, ymax=1, where=myProc9['TAG_2503']==True, facecolor='green', alpha=.5)
```

But as I would like to plot against the original datetime because I would like to share the x-Axis, so the only option I can see is to plot everything against `myProc9['timedelta'].astype('timedelta64[ns]')/np.timedelta64(1,'s')` and relabel the x-Axis.

I checked different pages about changing the datetime-format, but `matplotlib.collections` does not seem to take anything, the usual error message is

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'
```

(or whatever else I tried, for various conversions between datetime formats see here: [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64))

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this (not use `matplotlib.collections`) or a different way of calling it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to delete the question, but maybe it will be usefull for somebody sometime.

`ax.fill_between(df.index, 0,1,where=df['TAG_2526'])`

does the job and seems fairly generous regarding timestamps.

Link: https://matplotlib.org/gallery/pyplots/whats_new_98_4_fill_between.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pyplots-whats-new-98-4-fill-between-py