# Calculate with different datetime formats, datetime and datetime64

Tags: python, datetime, datetime64

I am trying to calculate the days between two dates:

First Date:

```
date = datetime.datetime.today() # {datetime} 2018-09-17 14:42:06.506541
```

Second date, extracted from a data frame:

```
date2 = data_audit.loc[(data_audit.Audit == audit), 'Erledigungsdatum'].values[0]
# {datetime64} 2018-07-23T00:00:00.000000000
```

The error:

> ufunc subtract cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('M8[ns]')

My next try was:

```
date = np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.now()) # {datetime64} 2018-09-17T14:48:16.599541
```

Which resulted in the following error (I pass the date as a parameter in a function):

> ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs
>   could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the
>   casting rule ''safe''

How should I approach this problem? The second one seems more logical to me, but I don't understand why I cant pass a simple date to a function.

Comment: Please see:
[Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64)

Answer (score 0):

I believe something like this should work for you:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np

# earlier being of type datetime64
earlier = np.datetime64(datetime.datetime.today())
# Converting datetime64 to datetime
earlier = earlier.astype(datetime.datetime)
now = datetime.datetime.today()

print(now-earlier)
```

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is as follows: Difference = date{datetime64 - date2{datetime64} | I cant pass the date to a function ->  ufunc 'bitwise_and' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Answer (score 0):

Let's try such approach

```
import datetime
date  = datetime.datetime.today()
date2 = '2018-07-23'#here could be your date converted to proper type
date2 = datetime.datetime.strptime(date2, '%Y-%m-%d')
difference = date- date2
difference = difference.days
```

And you can apply `df.some_col_with_difference.astype('timedelta64[D]')` to whole column in dataframe as well