# while converting a pd timestamp to date throws an error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am reading this data from my framework and getting it as below:

```
mped_date = pd.to_datetime(metadata['MPED'].values[0])

>> mped_date: 2017-12-31 00:00:00
type(mped_date)
>> mped_date: <class 'pandas._libs.tslib.Timestamp'>
```

I have other variables which are of type date and I am unable to compare this with them.I get the below error

> TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'

**Can someone guide me to convert the mped_date to date type ?**

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64

Comment: The to_pydatetime method seems to be a much more straightforward approach than the answers suggested in the reported duplicate. Perhaps it wasn't available when that question was posted five years ago.

Comment: @codingatty: Yes, please post your solution on the target question and we can upvote it there. We need to prevent duplicates proliferating.

Comment: OK, posted there.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use pandas, but the pandas doc shows a `pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime` method that sounds like it will do the conversion you need: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.to_pydatetime.html