# How to convert String to Numpy Datetime64 from a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I'm dealing with a DataFrame that contains column of time like "hh:mm:ss" and I need to convert those values to the NumPy `datetime64` type.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [dict(voie="V3", Start="06:10", End='06:20'),
            dict(voie="V5", Start='06:26', End='06:29'),
            dict(voie="V3", Start='06:20', End='06:30'),
            dict(voie="V5", Start='06:32', End='06:35')]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#df = df['Start'].to-datetime64()
```

I need to convert the column `Start` and `End` from type `string` to `datetime64`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) for each column. For example:

```
df.End = pd.to_datetime(df.End)
df.End
0   2019-05-15 06:20:00
1   2019-05-15 06:29:00
2   2019-05-15 06:30:00
3   2019-05-15 06:35:00
Name: End, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

You can also use the [`pandas.DataFrame.astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html) method of the DataFrame.

```
df.End = df.End.astype('datetime64[ns]')
df.End
0   2019-05-15 06:20:00
1   2019-05-15 06:29:00
2   2019-05-15 06:30:00
3   2019-05-15 06:35:00
Name: End, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

#### Regarding `pd.Timestamp` and `np.datetime64`

That is a complicated relationship. The `.values` attribute of the series will be an array of type `np.datetime64`, while the type of a single entry will be `pd.Timestamp`. As far as I know there is nothing you can do with `np.datetime64` that you can't with `pd.Timestamp`. There is a nice little graphic in [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64/21916253#21916253) that might help. Deep down within the `pd.to_datetime` code you will see that in fact when passed a `pd.Series` each entry is converted to `np.datetime64`. It isn't until you access an item in the series that it is converted into a `pd.Timestamp` (see [pandas._libs.index.get_value_at](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/0.24.x/pandas/_libs/index.pyx#L43-L45)).

Comment: It only changes the the type from String to Timestamp.

Comment: @Mohammed see my edits. I hope that helps make it more clear. The Timestamp you see is only a top layer that pandas uses when you are accessing elements. The actual data itself is of datetime64 type.