# substracting date times in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i've data frame is this

```
In[1]: df1
Out[1]
   Loan Date Negotiation
   2019-03-31
   2019-03-31
   2019-03-31

as Loan Date Negotiation           datetime64[ns]
```

so i wanna make function to subtract 2 days from it. if last the day of the month is sunday, i will subtract 2 days from it.

From dataframe above, 2019-03-31 Is sunday,

i've tried but it's fail, this is

````
 def subtractingDate(dateTime):
     dateTimestamp = pd.Timestamp(dateTime)
     newDate = dateTimestamp - pd.Timedelta("2 days")
     return newDate

 dfMARET.loc[dfMARET["Loan Date Negotiation"].dt.dayofweek == 6, "New Date"] = subtractingDate(dfMARET["Loan Date Negotiation"])

*note: 6 is for sunday

So the error is


TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-cc2a3348e6ce> in <module>
     16 # a = subtractingDate(dfMARET["Loan Date Negotiation"])
     17 # a
---> 18 dfMARET.loc[dfMARET["Loan Date Negotiation"].dt.dayofweek == 6, "New Date"] = subtractingDate(dfMARET["Loan Date Negotiation"])
     19 dfMARET
     20 
​
<ipython-input-9-cc2a3348e6ce> in subtractingDate(dateTime)
     10 
     11 def subtractingDate(dateTime):
---> 12     dateTimestamp = pd.Timestamp(dateTime)
     13     newDate = dateTimestamp - pd.Timedelta(days = 2)
     14     return newDate
​
pandas\_libs\tslibs\timestamps.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp.__new__()
​
pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion.convert_to_tsobject()```
````

**so my expectation would be**

```
 Loan Date Negotiation
 2019-03-29
 2019-03-29
 2019-03-29
```

Ther's solution in pandas?

thank's

Comment: Can you edit your post to include `df1["Loan Date Negotiation"].dtype` and the exact error that you get?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert datetime64 to Timestamp first, you can use:

```
df['Date'] = [pd.Timestamp(x) for x in df['Date']]
```

and use `timedelta()`:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
dt = pd.Timestamp(2019,3,31)
new_dt = dt-timedelta(days=2)

new_dt
> datetime.datetime(2019, 3, 29, 0, 0)

new_dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
> '2019-03-29'
```

Or on whole column `Date` with:

```
df['New_Date'] = df['Date']-timedelta(days=2)
```

**EDIT: Full example:**

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[np.datetime64(datetime(2019, 3, 31))],
                    [np.datetime64(datetime(2019, 3, 27))],
                    [np.datetime64(datetime(2019, 3, 24))]], 
                   columns=['Loan Date Negotiation'])
df1
```

[image]

```
df1['Loan Date Negotiation'].dtype
> dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

`M8[ns]` is a specific type of `datetime64[ns]`, so there should be no difference in further processing.

If you want to subtract two days only if the day is a sunday, you can use `np.where()`:

```
df1['New_Date'] = np.where(df1['Loan Date Negotiation'].dt.dayofweek==6, 
         df1['Loan Date Negotiation']-timedelta(days=2), 
         df1['Loan Date Negotiation'])
```

[image]

Dates at index 0 and 2 were sundays and got 2 days subtracted. Date at index 1 was not touched.

**Alternative via list comprehension over every single Timestamp**

```
df1['New_Date'] = [x-timedelta(days=2) if x.weekday()==6 else x for x in df1['Loan Date Negotiation']]
```

Comment: @charismabathara what exactly does not work? I added a full example with two alternatives. Could you try them?

Answer (score 0):

You're close!  You just need to change what you pass into `Timedelta()`.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd

ts = pd.Timestamp(2017, 1, 1, 12)
days = pd.Timedelta(days=2)
print(days)
print(ts)
print(ts - days)
```

Output:

```
2 days 00:00:00
2017-01-01 12:00:00
2016-12-30 12:00:00
```

Comment: how can i convert my datetime64[ns] types into timestamp sir? i've already tried with pd.Timestamp(df["Date"]). but it doesnt give a correct results. it giving so many nan

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64

Comment: Also, do you actually need that kind of time precision for what you're doing?  Maybe it would be easier if you didn't need to use datetime64.

Comment: @charisma bathara, you can use list comprehension to convert datetime64 to Timestamp, see my answer. :-)

Comment: @rkor Datatime64 is from my excel import

Comment: @charismabathara can you post the code that does the import?