# Converting numpy64 objects to Pandas datetime

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Question is pretty self-explanatory. I am finding that `pd.to_datetime` isn't changing anything about the object type and using `pd.Timestampe()`directly is bombing out.

Before this is marked a duplicate of [Converting between datetime, Timestamp and datetime64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64), I am struggling at changing an entire column of a dataframe not just one datetime object. Perhaps that was in the article but I didn't see it in the top answer.

I will add that my error is occurring when I try to get unique values from the dataframes column. Is using unique converting the dtype to something unwanted?

Comment: Unfortunately your problem is not clear. Please see [how to create good pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and create a [mcve] for your question

Answer (score 1):

The method you mentioned `pandas.to_datetime()` will work on scalars, Series and whole DataFrame if you need, so:

```
dataFrame['column_date_converted'] = pd.to_datetime(dataFrame['column_to_convert'])
```