# time difference between datetime.time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

Lets say I have a dataframe:

```
1027   2019-01-01 07:17:00
479    2019-01-01 07:10:00
480    2019-01-01 06:10:00
```

and I have a variable:

```
x=datetime.time(8,0)
```

How I can get the difference (in minutes) between each row and `x`?

I've tried:

```
row['date'].time() - x
```

But got:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 
>       'datetime.time'

[image]

Comment: It this a typo: should `miniute=0` be `minute=0` ?

Comment: yes you are right there is a type here but not in the code.

Comment: Please show your timedelta and substraction code, as well as the exact error message.  Also, did you convert `datetime` or `timestamp` to be the same type before calculations?

Comment: ive converted the rows in the df to:
 the row['date'].time() 
so now both are datetime.time (hour, minute)

Comment: Please include the code you tried that did not work, and include the "errors" (messages) it produced.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Most questions require a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so please review this topic, and include all pertinent info we might need to help solve your issue. Please also correct punctuation/capitalization/grammar/typos in your posts, to keep the quality of SO high, and so other volunteers do not have to do it for you.  Proper grammar shows attention to detail, respect, and volunteers are more likely to their time to *your post* when it is well formed.  Some posting guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: Is this post helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64

Answer (score 1):

`time` doesn't support subtractions, use `datetime` instead

```
In [14]: x = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 8, 00, 00)

In [15]: y = datetime(2019, 1, 1, 7, 17, 00)

In [16]: x
Out[16]: datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 8, 0)

In [17]: y
Out[17]: datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1, 7, 17)

In [18]: x - y
Out[18]: datetime.timedelta(seconds=2580)
```

Comment: thanks but i can't do that. Y is date value from a data frame so I cannot put any date in x and i can only change Y into Y.time() and then i get (7,17)

Comment: then it would be helpful to include that information into your original question.  You don't specify anything about pandas or data frames in your question, which means I thought you were working with straight Python.

Answer (score 1):

Using `df['date'].dt.minute` will return a value of the minutes (type integer), then you can subtract your variable from that value.

```
x = 8
df['date'].dt.minute - x
```

> ```
> 0     9
> 1     2
> 2     2
> Name: date, dtype: int64
> ```

I think the solution I presented above is what you asked for, however, I think you might want to investigate whether [`pandas.to_timedelta()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) is more helpful for you.!

Comment: Please `edit` to include your final suggested code (the "substraction" line you suggest), to make this a complete answer.  Thanks, and Welcome to SO.  Your contributions are appreciated :-)

Comment: I embedded the image, but you need to put code in text/code format on SO, as it isn't as easy to read code in image form (esp on mobile devices), nor can it be copy-pasted into editors. Lines indented by 4 spaces are converted to "code" formatting - see sidebar for additional MarkDown hints. Please review [Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for your next posts: [How to Post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [more](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Thanks, @SherylHohman .  Since the code runs and displays the same as my screenshot, I've removed my screenshot.