# Loss of data type when converting numpy.ndarry.tolist?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

So I have an `ndarray` similar to this example:

```
dates = ['3/1/2020','4/15/2020','7/21/2020']
darray = np.asarray([dateutil.parser.parse(d) for d in dates], dtype='datetime64[ns]')

>>> array(['2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-04-15T00:00:00.000000000',
   '2020-07-21T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]') 

darray.tolist()

>>> [1583020800000000000, 1586908800000000000, 1595289600000000000]
```

So I'm assuming it's converting to number of nanoseconds since the POSIX origin (1970-01-01). Is there a way to avoid this loss of data type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally `tolist` is better than `list`.  It works all-the-way down, and is faster.  `list` just iterates on the first dimension.  But the conversion to native Python types depends on dtype.  In this case the time units make a difference.

```
In [559]: arr = np.array(['2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000', '2020-04-15T00:00:00.000000000', 
     ...:    '2020-07-21T00:00:00.000000000'], dtype='datetime64[ns]')                         
In [560]: arr.shape                                                                            
Out[560]: (3,)
In [561]: arr.dtype                                                                            
Out[561]: dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

`list` is the equivalent of `[x for x in arr]`, iteration on the first dimension:

```
In [562]: list(arr)                                                                            
Out[562]: 
[numpy.datetime64('2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2020-04-15T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2020-07-21T00:00:00.000000000')]
```

`tolist` converts it to Python objects - all the way down:

```
In [563]: arr.tolist()                                                                         
Out[563]: [1583020800000000000, 1586908800000000000, 1595289600000000000]
```

While `ns` gives an integer, Other time units give different results:

```
In [564]: arr.astype('datetime64[D]')                                                          
Out[564]: array(['2020-03-01', '2020-04-15', '2020-07-21'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
In [565]: arr.astype('datetime64[D]').tolist()                                                 
Out[565]: 
[datetime.date(2020, 3, 1),
 datetime.date(2020, 4, 15),
 datetime.date(2020, 7, 21)]

In [566]: arr.astype('datetime64[s]').tolist()                                                 
Out[566]: 
[datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 15, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2020, 7, 21, 0, 0)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
>>> list(darray)
[numpy.datetime64('2020-03-01T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2020-04-15T00:00:00.000000000'),
 numpy.datetime64('2020-07-21T00:00:00.000000000')]
```

The difference is that `np.ndarray.tolist()` converts values to Python types, whereas `list(...)` leaves the objects as they are. Internally of course they both contain 64-bit integers either way. If you want to convert to Python datetime objects, have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64). Unfortunately it's not as convenient as it could be.

Comment: Thanks for this, should have found it. Guess I need to learn more numpy and the difference between `list()` and `tolist()`

Comment: It's a subtle enough difference, so that's understandable. I've added a note on that now.