# how to declare arguments as datetime64 inside a function?

Tags: python, pandas, function, datetime

I am trying to apply the next function in which two `datetime64` pandas dataframe columns are arguments:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

def set_dif_months_na(start_date, end_date):
    if (pd.isnull(start_date) and pd.notnull(end_date)):
        return None
    elif (pd.notnull(start_date) and pd.isnull(end_date)):
        return None
    elif (pd.isnull(start_date) and pd.isnull(end_date)):
        return None
    else:
        start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
        end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
    return abs((end_date.year - start_date.year) * 12 + (end_date.month - start_date.month))
```

This function is intended to get month difference as integer given two dates as arguments, else it has to return `None`.

When I apply it to a new pandas dataframe column as this:

```
df['new_col'] = [set_dif_months_na(date1, date2)
                                          for date1,date2 in 
                                          zip(df['date1'], df['date2'])]
```

The next error arises:

> TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp

How could I adjust the function in order to properly apply it over a new pandas dataframe column?

Comment: The error says you already have pd.Timestamp, why would you need strptime at all? To only get the date, use `.floor('d')`

Comment: With `strptime` I am trying to declare arguments as a `datetime64` object, how could I properly set the arguments as `datetime64` ?

Comment: It seems you *already have* that dtype...

Comment: Yes the columns are `datetime64`, however the function does not recognize them as `datetime64`

Comment: What the error tells you is that `start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y")` makes no sense since `start_date` already is datetime64 / pd.Timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By changing `start_date` and `end_date` setting from `strptime` to `pd.to_datetime` the function worked without any error:

```
def set_dif_months_na(start_date, end_date):
    if (pd.isnull(start_date) and pd.notnull(end_date)):
        return None
    elif (pd.notnull(start_date) and pd.isnull(end_date)):
        return None
    elif (pd.isnull(start_date) and pd.isnull(end_date)):
        return None
    else:
        start_date = pd.to_datetime(start_date,  format="%d/%m/%Y")
        end_date = pd.to_datetime(end_date, format="%d/%m/%Y")
    return abs((end_date.year - start_date.year) * 12 + (end_date.month - start_date.month))
```

Answer (score 1):

You see, `pandas` uses `numpy` to parse dates, and `numpy.datetime64` is not directly compatible with `datetime.datetime`, which you are trying to use.

There's a couple of different solutions, but if you want to use `datetime`, which is more readable in my opinion, you may do something like this. First we define a function to convert between both data types (got it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13704307/14298880)):

```
def numpy2datetime(date):
    return (datetime.
            datetime.
            utcfromtimestamp(
                            (date - np.datetime64('1970-01-01T00:00:00')) / 
                            np.timedelta64(1, 's'))
                            )
```

Then you may be able to do what you want by changing your function from :

```
start_date = datetime.strptime(start_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
end_date = datetime.strptime(end_date, "%d/%m/%Y")
```

to

```
start_date = numpy2datetime(start_date)
end_date = numpy2datetime(end_date)
```

This should work. However, I may have some additional suggestions for you. First, you can change all your `if` and `elif` to a single one by using the `or` logical operator:

```
if pd.isnull(start_date) or pd.isnull(end_date):
    return None
else:
    start_date = numpy2datetime(start_date)
    end_date = numpy2datetime(end_date)
    return abs((end_date.year - start_date.year) * 12 + (end_date.month - start_date.month))
```

And a last one is regarding your list comprehension. You don't need `zip` at all, since both columns are within the same dataframe. You can simply do:

```
df['new_col'] = [set_dif_months_na(date1, date2)
                                          for date1,date2 in 
                                          df[['date1','date2']].values]
```

Don't know if it's faster, but at least it's clearer.

Hope it's useful. And let us know if you have any further issues.

Comment: pandas handles datetime.datetime objects pretty well but that is not the point here I think. The OP should work with pandas datetime only, and in fact the error tells me he already does

Comment: I've just tryed to follow OP's line of thought, converting dates to `datetime` and then getting the difference in months. Feel free to suggest a solution using pure pandas, which will indeed be more efficient