# Pandas strange behaviour of datetime object

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, data-processing

I am trying to demonstrate what is my problem. I really do not understand, why `PyNative` `<class 'datetime.datetime'>` object is replaced with `Pandas` custom object `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`.

```py
import typing
from dateutil.parser import parse

def _normalize_users_dataframe(row: pd.core.series.Series) -> pd.core.series.Series:
    last_seen: typing.Union[str, datetime.datetime] = row.get('last_seen', '')
    if last_seen:
        last_seen = parse(last_seen)
        row['last_seen'] = last_seen
        print(row['last_seen'][0].__class__.__mro__) # This shows me that, it is <class 'datetime.datetime'> object, which is PyNative datetime.
    return row

def process_users_dataframe(filepath: str) -> pd.core.frame.DataFrame:
    df: pd.core.frame.DataFrame = pd.read_csv(filepath, sep='\t')
    df.rename(columns=mapping, inplace=True)
    df.replace({np.nan: None}, inplace=True)
    df = df.apply(_normalize_users_dataframe, axis=1)
    print(row['last_seen'][0].__class__.__mro__) # This shows me that, it is <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>, which is `Pandas` specific object.
    return df


def main() -> None:
    process_users_dataframe('<dir>')
```

Inside `normalize_users_dataframe()` function, when I am trying to `print` `last_seen` column series, it shows me that `dtype` is `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`, which is fine, but after run `apply()` method on `DataFrame` which returns new `DataFrame` object,`last_seen` `dtype` became `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>`.

How this happens ? Maybe deep implementation detail ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13703720/converting-between-datetime-timestamp-and-datetime64  Maybe the second answer in this question will help?

Comment: @Chris Thank you for reply, I can fix this but question is why I am getting this behaviour.

Comment: why would you use `datetime.datetime` in the first place? Note that pandas will always try to use its own datetime (pd.Timestamp), unless you have a mixed datatype Series.

Comment: [Pandas supports](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) the `numpy.timedelta64` and `numpy.datetime64` dtypes for datetime operations. It is not built upon the standard library, and there are many inconsistencies between the two (mostly with timezone handling). Really, if working with pandas you shouldn't use `datetime`