# Comparing times by considering time zones

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pytz

According to [Convert UTC to local time to UTC in Python and Google App Engine](http://appengine.sitebob.com/convert-utc-to-local-time-to-utc-in-python/), to correctly compare the times of now and a target time (considering different time zones), I have to convert the target time to UTC as follows:

```
import pytz

def toUTC(date, tz):
    tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Taipei')
    utc = pytz.timezone('UTC')
    d_tz = tz.normalize(tz.localize(date))
    d_utc = d_tz.astimezone(utc)
    return d_utc

days = 10
minutes = 20
targetTime = datetime.datetime(2012,12,22,0,0,0)
targetTime = targetTime + datetime.timedelta(days=days, minutes=minutes)
targetTime = toUTC(targetTime) 

if targetTime < datetime.datetime.now():
    ...
```

Questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. There is an error message:

   `TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

   How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its because one of your `datetime` objects has a timezone set and the other one doesn't.
take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/python-cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065164/how-to-make-an-unaware-datetime-timezone-aware-in-python)