# Converting Twitter time zone and performing searches

Tags: python, twitter

I have a large set of Tweets and I need to retrieve tweets from one week period, one day period etc. So, I want to specify a start and end date and retrieve all the data that matches the query. Now, I have this code:

```
pac=timezone('US/Pacific')
utc=timezone('UTC')
start_created_at = datetime.strptime(tweet['created_at'], '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
start_utc_created_at = utc.localize(start_created_at)
start_pac_created=start_utc_created_at.astimezone(pac)
```

which gives me an output like this

```
2014-01-11 10:51:11-08:00
```

I am still trying to learn how to manipulate date/time so I would appreciate any hints on how to perform queries and select tweets from a specific time period that does not require manually inputing the whole string but instead of that, something like 01/01/2014-01/10/2014 or something easily managable.

Comment: If you're asking how to query your database, a bit of info on the database and table schema might help

Comment: sorry! edited! I don't want to query the database at this moment, just wanted to learn the basics. Sorry about that!

Comment: Perfect. That's what I assumed, but I wanted to make sure. I've updated my answer below to reflect that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're already converting it to a `datetime` object, which is 100% correct.

We need to compare that against two other `datetime` objects, representing the start and end of our date range. Create the start timestamp by passing year, month, day into the datetime class:

```
start_timestamp = datetime.datetime(2014, 1, 14)
```

Now create the end timestamp by adding a `timedelta` object equal to one week, (7 days)

```
end_timestamp = start_timestamp + datetime.timedelta(7)
```

Last, ensure the tweet timestamp is between start and end:

```
if start_timestamp < start_created_at < end_timestamp:
    print 'yay!'
```

Comment: I am getting an error: TypeError: can't compare offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: Check out this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/a/796019/3130539. You can either add timezone info, or remove timezone info to make the "naivete" match