# Convert datetime.min into offset aware datetime

Tags: python, timezone

I need to subtract a timezone aware datetime.now() with datetime.min, but i keep getting this error **TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes**. Please help!

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
now = datetime.now(timezone('Europe/Dublin'))
result = now - datetime.min
```

Comment: I guess you have checked that answer right ? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes)

Comment: Yes, I have checked this post the first answer is to remove timezone awareness and the second solution was for making datetime.now() aware, but my requirement is to make datetime.min aware

Comment: MAking datetime.min aware is going to be... interesting. Do it the other way round

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can convert it to `UTC`:

```
In [1]: from datetime import datetime

In [2]: import pytz

In [3]: dt_min = datetime.min

In [4]: print(dt_min)
0001-01-01 00:00:00

In [5]: dt_min = dt_min.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)

In [6]: print(dt_min)
0001-01-01 00:00:00+00:00
```

So your code would be:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
now = datetime.now(pytz.timezone('Europe/Dublin'))
dt_min = datetime.min
result = now - dt_min.replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC)
print(result)

output:
737202 days, 7:27:48.839353
```

Comment: Better answer than mine

Comment: pytz is now included in `datetime`