# Firebase Firestore Server timestamp vs Python Datetime?

Tags: python, firebase, datetime, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm using the python admin sdk for my browser game... but I've run through some issues...

I use timestamps to track when something was created in my game, by using the default timestamp that comes with the library as shown here

```py
from firebase_admin import firestore, credentials as _cred

# setup client here

firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP
```

but lets say I wanted to compare this to a normal datetime like so

```py
>>> import datetime
>>> o = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> type(o)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> userDict = db.collection("users").document("test").get().to_dict()

>>> type(userDict['creation_time'])
<class 'google.api_core.datetime_helpers.DatetimeWithNanoseconds'>
>>> userDict['creation_time']-datetime.datetime.now()

TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes
```

is there any way I can subtract the two to get a normal datetime like so?

```py
>>> o - datetime.datetime.now()
datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=86381, microseconds=61146)
```

If so could you tell me please? That would make my day, Thanks for reading through my problem, I hope you can help!

Comment: is not clear for me on you code if you are converting the `firestore.SERVER_TIMESTAMP` to a datetime before trying to subtract it, are you doing that? If so, you might wan't to try removing the timezone awareness from your datetimes, like in this [community answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes), note that you might have do add some time or subtract it depending on the timezone but this could work.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `TypeError: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes` and `datetime.datetime.now()` returns a timezone naive datetime. This seems to be the problem. So, you could try to use a timezone aware datetime for subtracting like so:

```
from datetime import timezone, datetime

userDict['creation_time'] - datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)
```