# Django: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

i have a 'free_trial' function in my app that allows users who have an account not older than 7 days to try my app.

user model

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    
        def free_trial(self):
            if (self.date_joined - datetime.now()) < timedelta(days=7):
                return True
```

templates

```
{% if user.free_trial %}

#Access Features

{% endif %}
```

but i'm getting this error on template `can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [timezone aware time](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#module-django.utils.timezone) for your calculation:

```
from django.utils.timezone import localdate

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):

    def free_trial(self):
        if (self.date_joined - localdate()) < timedelta(days=7):
            return True
```

Answer (score 0):

One of those datetimes is in a particular time zone ("offset-aware"), and the other is not in any particular timezone ("offset-naïve"), see [this part of the Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#aware-and-naive-objects) and [this previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes). They can't be sensibly compared — you either need to add timezone information to one, remove timezone information from the other, or use a seconds-since-the-epoch representation for both. Which one you want to do depends on how you want your application to behave.