# Template tags to work with time in Django

Tags: python, django

Please tell me how can I use Django to output the time in this format, such as "Last Monday" or "Last Friday" if the difference between the dates is not more than a week.

Comment: Django has humanize but it does not output strings in a way you want it, you should either work out your solution or find package for which recommending is not in a scope of this site
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/humanize/

Comment: Got it, thanks for the answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd write a custom filter for this (this assumes that `value` is a date in the past). This is quick-and-dirty, and you may want more logic to accommodate times crossing over midnight to accurately report "Earlier today," "Yesterday," etc.

```py
from datetime import datetime
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name='relative_date')
def relative_date(value):
    timespan = datetime.now() - value

    if timespan.days == 0:
        return 'Within the last day'

    if timespan.days == 1:
        return 'Yesterday'
    
    if timespan.days <= 7:
        return f"Last {value.strftime('%A')}"

    return value.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') # Or whatever format you want to use for older dates
```

Then in your template:

`{{ some_date|relative_date }}`

Read the [custom template tags and filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) documentation for info on where the file containing this function should live and how to import it into your template files.

Comment: Looks beautiful. Thank you so much)

Comment: can't subtract offset-naive and offset-aware datetimes

Comment: Ah, you must be using timezones in your Django settings. See this thread (and specifically this answer) for information on dealing with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes/25662061#25662061