# How to get difference between current timestamp and a different timestamp?

Tags: python, datetime, unix-timestamp

I am trying get difference between two timestamps and check if its greater than 30 mins

```
timestamp1 = 1668027512
now = datetime.now(tz)
```

And this is what i am trying to do

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz as tz
tz = tz.timezone('UTC')
import time

timestamp1 = 1668027512
timestamp1 = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(timestamp1)).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
print(timestamp1)
now = datetime.now(tz).strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
print(now)
print(timestamp1 - now)
```

This is giving me this error

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str
```

so i tried to convert them to unix timestamp and then do the difference

```
d1_ts = time.mktime(timestamp1.timetuple())
d2_ts = time.mktime(now.timetuple())

print(d1_ts - d2_ts)
```

But now the error is this

```
'str' object has no attribute 'timetuple'
```

This `datetime` package is confusing,
What am i missing here ?

Comment: You want to subtract the `datetime` objects themselves.  Only call `.strftime()` on them for display purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

# 30 minutes times 60 seconds
thirty_minutes = 30 * 60

past_timestamp = 1668027512
now_timestamp = datetime.now().timestamp()

if (now_timestamp - past_timestamp) > thirty_minutes:
    # do your thing
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing is that when you use  `.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")` you are converting the class datetime to string and you can't compare strings.

I suggest you to only utilize yours variables as strings at the moment you are printing them (but that depends on your goals with the variables).

Also, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796008/cant-subtract-offset-naive-and-offset-aware-datetimes) you can solve the problem with datetime operations that are build upon a specific timezone. For this you have to include the `now = now.replace(tzinfo=None)`

So your code would be

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz as tz
tz = tz.timezone('UTC')
import time

timestamp1 = 1668027512
timestamp1 = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(int(timestamp1))

print(timestamp1.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))
now = datetime.now(tz)
print(now.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"))

now = now.replace(tzinfo=None)
print(timestamp1 - now)
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to always work with aware datetimes in order to avoid issues and ensure reproducibility, especially if you'd like to share your code.

`utcfromtimestamp()` unfortunately returns a naive datetime, meaning it doesn't set the `tzinfo` attribute.
It's better to use `fromtimestamp()` and specify the timezone.

From `pytz` you can directly import the `UTC` constant, for convenience.

You can use `timedelta()` to express the time delta.

Parenthesis are not mandatory in the comparison, thanks to the operator precedence rules

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import UTC

dt1 = datetime.fromtimestamp(1668027512, UTC)
now = datetime.now(UTC)
if now - dt1 > timedelta(minutes=30):
    print("period expired")
```